# Screenshot of the Week #47

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16054) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16092)*

---

Hello and welcome to the forty-seventh edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [arghtype's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16057/8350) of a serious person in a serious cutscene in [dark-souls-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-souls-3) with 14 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2021-09-13, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2021-09-20, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## No Theme Week

There's no theme this week, so just send us your best (or worst) screenshots!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Comment: There I go again..

Comment: @Joachim I promise I had a reminder set mentally in my mind, but then Dad duties took over...

Comment: @TimmyJim It's obviously completely fine :)

Comment: @Joachim We're just outsourcing moderator duties to Arts & Crafts Stack Exchange

Comment: @Wipqozn Smart. I was never notified of that extra responsibility, though, but it comes naturally :)

Comment: @Wipqozn Can you please mark [the winner](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16068/171580) as accepted?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cuddling my beloved winged partner Phosphor from [immortals-fenyx-rising](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/immortals-fenyx-rising)

[image]

Comment: Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 10):

Brotherly love from [luigis-mansion-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luigis-mansion-3)

[image]

Answer (score 8):

A wild F. Simiayarnica discovered on the planet Enianes IV in [no-mans-sky](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/no-mans-sky).

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[image]

That almost would've been bad for my [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) mining trip.

Comment: Slicedlime once had a charity event during which people could rebind his Minecraft controls with donations. When mining was set to F1, he found a greeeat way to prevent the UI from flickering, which your screenshot reminded me of: https://youtu.be/_qJHEPecdvg?t=808

Answer (score 6):

Its sad splatfests are not a thing anymore. They did have the funniest things. Screenshot from [splatoon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/splatoon)

[image]

Comment: +1 I love that Bender's quote

Comment: I can't believe this is in this game - I'm cracking up!

Comment: @TimmyJim iirc in the first Splatoon you were able to draw something and post it on Splatoon miiverse, some of them will appear randomly in game on those banners

Comment: @pinckerman if that is the case, it looks perfect!

Comment: @pinckerman yeah the first splatoon had integration with miiverse and during slatfests you could do a banner for your team, and it would cycle through a few of them on the plaza. I do expect that this was checked by something at nintendo, so there was no profanity in the bundle of banners that would get shown. So that thing did get through nintendo censors lol

Answer (score 6):

Trash Pirate ship in [borderlands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borderlands)

[image: Trash Pirate Ship]

Comment: FWIW, it was this screenshot that made me wonder if it was possible to [disable the HUD](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/390362/28182)

Comment: Too bad there's no photo mode

Comment: @pinckerman yeah it's what led me down the path of disabling the HUD, luckily it is something toggle-able with the right configuration set, I just haven't been back to the Hyperion Dump (where this ship is) at the right time of day to get the sunset shot.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Dogi in Ys: The Oath in Felghana]

I shudder to think what Dogi's house might look like in [ys-oath-in-felghana](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ys-oath-in-felghana)