# Screenshot of the Week #48: Nighttime

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16106)*

---

Hello and welcome to the forty-eighth edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [pinckerman's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16068/163757) of their winged partner Phosphor from the game [imortals-fenyx-rising](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/imortals-fenyx-rising) with 11 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2021-09-27, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2021-10-04, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Theme - Nighttime

This weeks theme is **Nighttime**!  Show us all of those beautiful nighttime landscapes, or creepy nighttime atmospheres, or anything with a nighttime theme!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Admiring the horizon of a ringed planet in [no-mans-sky](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/no-mans-sky)

[image]

Answer (score 10):

The coronation of Cerys under the sacred oak Gedyneith on Ard Skellig. "*Among them - Geralt of Rivia*."

[image]

[the-witcher-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-witcher-3)

Comment: Man it be awesome to have this as a painting mounted on a wall

Comment: @TimmyJim That's funny: I kept thinking I should make a painting of this :)

Answer (score 10):

[luigis-mansion-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luigis-mansion-3) gives some good reasons to be scared of the dark

[image]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Horizon: Zero Dawn]

A Settlement lit up at night in [horizon-zero-dawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-zero-dawn)

Answer (score 7):

A relaxing night in [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft)

[image]

Comment: There are flowers that glow now in Minecraft?

Comment: There were with whatever mods I was using at the time! Looks like Botania, maybe?

Answer (score 6):

A majestic Suicune under a starry sky in [new-pokemon-snap](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-pokemon-snap)

[image: Suicine under a starry sky]

Answer (score 4):

Survived the first night with a blood moon in [7-days-to-die](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7-days-to-die):

[image: Sunrise in Navezgane, "7 Days to Die"]

Comment: I was hoping to see a 7 days to die blood moon!

Comment: @Timmy I'm confused by that comment, do you mean you wanted to actually _see_ the blood moon? (I've never played this)

Comment: @n00dles I was hoping someone would post a screenshot for this week's theme of this game, particularly the blood moon, which in this game, occurs once a week  by default (in game time). A blood moon makes the sky all red, and the zombies go berserk and try to kill you by any means necessary.

Comment: Got it lol Blood Moon!

Comment: @n00dles This shot happens to be just before 4 AM. The blood moon is over and it's just before sunrise. The rising of the blood moon itself would be more visually impressive, but I didn't have one handy at the time.