# Screenshot of the Week #101

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest is over.

*[previous contest](//meta.arqade.com/q/16898/) | [next contest](//meta.arqade.com/q/16933/)*

Hello and welcome to the **101<sup>st</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Dragonrage](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16911/222022)'s resubmission of [Pinckerman](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16879/222022)'s screenshot of a dramatic sunset from [horizon-forbidden-west](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-forbidden-west) won our 100th Screenshot of the Week celebration with 12 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2023-10-23, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2023-10-30, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## No Theme

There is no theme this week.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Comment: Glad you posted this Joachim, I didn't want to seem egocentric and congratulate myself

Comment: @pinckerman Haha, yeah, I know the feeling, but it would have been completely fine, of course! (At least, that's what I was told..)

Comment: thanks for posting. I was distracted by the events that occurred today, and forgot.

Comment: @Dragonrage Very understandable.

Comment: Why no theme? Let’s do Halloween / Spooky season

Comment: @arghtype this will run until 30 october, Halloween could definitely be the next one

Comment: @arghtype Halloween is the current one. Joachim, could you mark the winner as accepted?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

---

[the-elder-scrolls-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-online)

Answer (score 11):

Autumnal greetings from [the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim).

[image]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Diablo IV]

Part of the Diablo IV story campaign, I forget which bit :D

Comment: NGL, this gives the same energy as the winner for [Character Customization](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16057/124566) contest

Answer (score 6):

Some night work in [snowrunner](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/snowrunner)

[image]

Comment: And where is the snow? 

Comment: @nobody It was all melted as part of a Halloween trick!

Answer (score 5):

Kril chilling on a cork in [anothers-crab-treasure](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anothers-crab-treasure)

[image: crab chilling on a cork]

Answer (score 4):

This was a fight I never wanted. Roxas vs. Sora [kingdom-hearts-2-final-mix](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom-hearts-2-final-mix)

[image]

Comment: Is this `kingdom-hearts-2` or `kingdom-hearts-2-final-mix`? I'm assuming the latter, since you're battling Roxas during this scene, rather it just being a cutscene

Comment: Oh yeah final mix. The one for PS2 I missed somehow. And I was batteling Roxas.

Answer (score 4):

Link ready to reap Ganon's soul in [zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom)

[image]