# Screenshot of the Tweak: title links back to original answer

Tags: feature-request, status-review, screenshot-of-the-week, screenshot-widget

I would like to propose an edit to the Screenshot of the Week widget: Have the title of the image (highlighted in the image below) link back to the original answer in the [screenshot-of-the-week](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screenshot-of-the-week) thread, i.c.:

[image: Sample of a better Screenshot of the Week.]

#### From:

```
<div class="s-sidebarwidget--item d-block ta-center">
  <b>
    [title]
  </b> 
  …
</div>
```

#### To:

```
<div class="s-sidebarwidget--item d-block ta-center">
  <b>
     <a href="https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15861/136881">
        [title]
     </a>
  </b>
  …
</div>
```

---

I have second proposed change for the Screenshot Widget, which can be found [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15896/222022).

Comment: I hope the bold text in the code shows up for everybody - if not, feel free to edit it.

Comment: nit -- instead of `<b>` should be `<strong>`. Unless its only purpose is to be bold in which case it should be a `<p>` tag or `<span>` with appropriate font-weight CSS. Not really relevant to the suggestion, though.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas It's a direct copy/paste from the website's code, so it may be wise to bring up on Meta SE.

Comment: I figured, hence the nit. ;)

Answer (score 4):

I've added [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) as it would be nice to get this into the backlog of tasks.

Nothing needs to be automagically detected or anything. What's required:

- A new field on the **Custom Sidebar Content** form (Mod Dashboard -> Links, under the Utilities header). Depending on how the other fields are stored, this might mean a new DB column.
- The <a> tag link as described by Joachim. I'd prefer if it had a `target="_blank"` attribute to open in a new tab, but that's just me.