# Screenshot of the Tweak: replace image with smaller version

Tags: feature-request, screenshot-of-the-week, screenshot-widget

I would like to propose an edit to the Screenshot of the Week widget: Have the image that appears in the widget be a smaller version of the original so that it doesn't unnecessarily drain resources. ([Shadow's answer here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15589/222022) originally pointed out the resource drain).

The link *might* need to be rewritten, depending on the way this code is generated (PHP?), as they currently have the same target:

```
<a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rybqs.jpg">
  <img class="wmx100" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rybqs.jpg" alt="">
</a>
```

If these links are not identical in the back-end code, we can simply replace the second with the medium-sized image generated by Imgur, i.c.

```
<img … src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rybqsm.jpg" …>
                                             ↑
```

---

I have another proposal to tweak the Screenshot widget, which can be found [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15895/222022).

Comment: Worth to mention that the resources being drained are of imgur, so no big deal for SE. The more important consideration is loading speed for slow connections.

Comment: @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard Well, also for loading the page. That original phrasing is probably a little off, but users having slow connections might benefit from this change.

Comment: I also seem to recall the image being un-clickable back before it was added to the site here. Clicking it now takes you to the full image. As long as that click still takes you to the full size image, I think this would be a good idea.

Comment: @BoogaRoo Yes, definitely, hence the change in only the <img> tag.

Comment: @Dragonrage (or any other mod): are you mods able to change the code, or should I bring this up at Meta? I feel like these changes would improve the widget, and very quickly and easy to implement, but haven't gotten any reaction all these years.

Comment: Actually on second thought, I'm taking this out of [status-review] for now, given that the [partnership with Imgur is ending and the exact replacement is a bit up in the air](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395024/179041). Once the migration has happened and things have settled, ping one of the mods (or use a flag) and we can add it back to review again.