# Screenshot of Week #50 - Halloween

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16106) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16136)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **50<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!  It's been almost two years since we started this community event, and this week marks a significant milestone!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Morgan's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16113/163757) of Mario looking a bit "dank" in [super-mario-odyssey](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-mario-odyssey) with 15 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot]

As mentioned, this is the **50<sup>th</sup>** edition of Screenshot of the Week. We are glad this event has made a lasting impact and seems to be enjoyed by everyone. Check out the [Hall of Fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) to see all the screenshot winners of the previous contests.

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2021-10-26, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2021-11-01, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Halloween

Last year around this time, we had a [Halloween themed contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15375/screenshot-of-the-week-contest-24-halloween), so it only seems appropriate to once again!  Submit your best Halloween themed screenshots! It could be your character dressed up for the occasion, or maybe a seasonally decorated environment, or possibly some creepy and spooky monsters!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Comment: Aww, I already submitted my [undead dogs](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15139/171580). :D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [blade-and-soul](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blade-and-soul)'s lobby, during the [Blade & Ghoul event](https://www.bladeandsoul.com/en-us/news/article/5681/blade-ghoul-is-now-live), looks so ominous!

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 13):

My pumpkin patch from my town in [animal-crossing-new-horizons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal-crossing-new-horizons)

[image: pumpkin patch]

Comment: Nice Harry Potter costume

Answer (score 9):

A beautifully detailed Screamer peering into your soul in [days-gone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/days-gone)

[image]

Comment: thanks i hate it

Comment: lol it catches your attention nicely. Took me a while to get it right.

Comment: wow, just a little too detailed

Answer (score 6):

Goofy just hanging out in Halloween Town’s Town Square in [kingdom-hearts-2.5-remix](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom-hearts-2.5-remix).

[image: goofy in Halloween town]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Terraria]

Getting my Water trough ruined during an Autumn Blood Moon in modded *Terraria*

Active Mods:

- Terraria Overhaul
- Calamity Mod
- Spirit Mod
- Thorium Mod
- Boss Checklist

Answer (score 5):

The Graveyard levels from [pacman-world-20th-anniversary](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pacman-world-20th-anniversary) definitely give off the Halloween vibes.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Things are starting to get a bit interesting in [hellblade-senuas-sacrifice](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hellblade-senuas-sacrifice):

[image]

Comment: Apologies, I have not played this game. I think there is a bit of context I am missing as to how it relates to Halloween.

Answer (score 4):

It's the Demoman's missing, possessed eyeball and boss of <strike>Vi</strike>... er, *Eye*aduct: **MONOCULUS!**

[image: Monoculus, the giant floating eyeball on Eyeaduct]

[team-fortress-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-fortress-2)