# Screenshot of Week #51

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16120) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16148)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **51<sup>st</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winners (yes plural!) of the previous contest! We had a tie this time around where two submissions both had 13 votes.

[Ismael Miguel's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16122/163757) of [blade-and-soul](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blade-and-soul)'s lobby for Halloween:

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

And [GammaGames's submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16132/163757) of their pumpkin patch in [animal-crossing-new-horizons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal-crossing-new-horizons):

[image: Last week's winning screenshot two]

Since we have two winners, we will rotate the winning screenshots on the main sites screenshot widget to showcase them both!

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2021-11-08, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2021-11-15, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## No Theme

There is no theme this week. Submit any video game screenshot of your liking!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Comment: So... we work with ties now? We've had at least two in the past, but something arbitrary decided the winner. I like this.

Comment: @Joachim I wasn't aware of previous ties in the past (or how they were handled), but I'm sure they happened.  I discussed with one of the other mods what we should do, and I figured just featuring both winners in the widget on the main site would be ok (next week we will feature the other winner).  The other idea was see if people in the Bridge chat would vote for us, but I didn't think it felt right to _ask_ for votes. But this time around, I am saving my vote in the case of a needed tie breaker!

Comment: @TimmyJim I am more than happy with a tie. And I'm also more than happy to share the hall of fame with GammaGames.

Comment: The tie was cool! I had forgotten to check the page over the weekend and it was a nice surprise. And congrats, @IsmaelMiguel ️

Comment: @GammaGames And congrats to you too!

Comment: When you say “ Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as […] simple filters,” how simple are we talking? New Horizons added a couple nice filters (oil painting, for example) that feel like more complicated than allowed but are included in the game.

Comment: @GammaGames if it's built into the game, I would say it's fine. Be sure to note that though. Also keep in mind that submissions are closed for this week!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Shattered Obelisk viewed from a distance in [new-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-world):

[image: shattered obelisk]

Answer (score 10):

Fireworks on the beach in [animal-crossing-new-horizons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal-crossing-new-horizons)

[image]

Answer (score 9):

The Nightshade Harbor moon looks amazing, after defeating Kaari Lord in Cold Storage, in [blade-and-soul](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blade-and-soul).

[image: screenshot]

For context, Cold Storage's entrance used to be in Nightshade Harbor, but the portal was removed before 2016.

It used to be possible to escape from Cold Storage to Nightshade Harbor, under the map, but the Unreal Engine 4 update doesn't let you anymore :(

The moon and the houses seen in the image are from Nightshade Harbor, but still visible in Cold Storage.

Answer (score 7):

Sonic is now ready to fight Frieza (just kidding), turning into Super Sonic in [sonic-the-hedgehog-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sonic-the-hedgehog-2)

[image: Super Sonic]

Comment: Nice! :) Is this emulated, or otherwise which release of Sonic 2 is this? (It's been ported and emulated a whole bunch of times).

Comment: @Robotnik yep, emulated and I don't remember how. I took this screenshot years ago, and just found it out of nowhere. It deserved to be posted

Comment: @Robotnik something tells me you are a sucker for Sonic screenshots ;)

Comment: @TimmyJim I don't know what you're talking about 

Comment: @TimmyJim who isn't? 

Answer (score 7):

Peaceful landscape

[hell-let-loose](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hell-let-loose)

[image]

Comment: +1 but, I don't buy the premise of a peaceful landscape. The drawn gun at the ready is a dead-giveaway. :-)

Answer (score 7):

A desert slave being stomped by an oppressive regime...
Another reason to KICK ASS in [metro-exodus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metro-exodus)
[image]