# Screenshot of the Week #52 - Hero Pose!

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## Competition Closed

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16136) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16160)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **52<sup>nd</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Timmy Jim's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16138/28182) shot of the Shattered Obelisk in [new-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-world) won with a handy 14 votes:

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2021-11-23, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2021-11-30, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Theme: Hero Pose

Show a character striking a cool pose for the camera!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Comment: 52nd? does that mean this it's the 2nd year annaversary?

Comment: [First post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14741/171580), 2019-11-27

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Strength Cape emote in [oldschool-runescape](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oldschool-runescape)

[image]

Comment: This brings back so many memories. The strength cape was my first skill cape

Comment: @Wondercricket in OSRS, my first 99 was thieving.  In RS3, I am not sure... probably one of the combat skills.

Answer (score 11):

*[Hey there, good lookin!](https://youtu.be/GLlLQ3LmZWU?t=410) I got a bucket o' chicken, let's do this!* - [team-fortress-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-fortress-2)

[image: Scout with Yeti]

Comment: Team Fortress did a good job with their videos.  I feel they are hidden gems.

Answer (score 9):

The most heroic of poses, brought to you by [west-of-loathing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/west-of-loathing)

[image]

Comment: Is he just sitting? Or is he doing... what dogs do when they have an itch...?

Comment: @TimmyJim The latter one.

Answer (score 7):

Hero *cough* *cough* pose!

[image]

*Arno in [assassins-creed-unity](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-unity)*

Answer (score 7):

All barriers dispersed! Ready for the final fight with Ganon in [zelda-ocarina-of-time](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-ocarina-of-time)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Final Fantasy XIV]

Readying my Final Attack in [final-fantasy-xiv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-xiv)