# Screenshot of the Week #53

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## Competition Closed

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16148) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16171)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **53<sup>rd</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winners of the previous contest! [Timmy Jim's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16151/28182) strength cape <strike>flex</strike> emote in [oldschool-runescape](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oldschool-runescape), and [Robotnik's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16152/28182) bucket of chicken proposition in [team-fortress-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-fortress-2) tied with 11 votes apiece:

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

[image: Last week's winning screenshot two]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2021-12-07, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2021-12-14, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## No Theme

No theme this week, post your best (or worst) screenshots!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Comment: The funny thing is that you're congratulating to yourself

Comment: I really like that bucket o' chicken proposition

Comment: @pinckerman [;)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Euvbc.jpg)

Comment: @JonathanDavidArndt I wish I had thought of that name for the actual competition haha

Comment: It's not rigged we swear!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Enjoying evening ride in [days-gone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/days-gone)

[image: should-i-pickup-this-hitchhiker]

Comment: It's such a shame, this game is relatively pretty to look at but the gameplay just didn't do it for me :\

Comment: @Kaizerwolf [“pretty”](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16123/124566)

Comment: @Wondercricket you sneaky beaky

Comment: @Kaizerwolf For me this game was actually a hidden gem. Of cause gameplay is repetitive just like for every other open world game. But the story is very satisfying and surprisingly long. There are bunch of interesting NPCs in the 2nd half of the game. Also leveling up feels rewarding: both skills and available weapons change gameplay completely. I definitely recommend this game, maybe you can try the easiest difficulty just to breeze through the story once.

Answer (score 15):

Even ghosts can be good boys [luigis-mansion-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luigis-mansion-3)

[image]

Answer (score 10):

The 'good' ending of [sonic-the-hedgehog](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sonic-the-hedgehog)

[image: Sonic 1 end screen]

Comment: Been a while since I've played Sonic 1. I've been delving into some old favourites via the Sega Mega Drive/Genesis Classics pack [on Steam](https://store.steampowered.com/app/34270/SEGA_Mega_Drive_and_Genesis_Classics/). (I've also just noticed the scanlines playing up a bit when shrunk by SE, open the full screenshot for the correct pattern)

Comment: Looks fine on laptop. Sonic was my era man! I painted a huge sonic and knuckles on my bedroom wall lol.

Comment: @n00dles Heh, it was my era too (if that wasn't obvious from my screenname lol). That wall sounds awesome! I'm jealous :O

Answer (score 10):

Felt like the right time of year, so I started yet another replay of [the-long-dark](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-long-dark). Here’s the view the morning after nearly freezing to death.

[image: the long dark]

Answer (score 10):

Dathomir looking gorgeous in [jedi-fallen-order](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jedi-fallen-order)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

My new pal Chomper in [days-gone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/days-gone)
He seems a bit "on edge" when you first meet him - He's had a hard life. Just don't touch his face - he doesn't like that.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Entering the Goron Cave for the first time in [zelda-majoras-mask](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-majoras-mask)

[image]

Comment: (Taken using Project64 v3) Clicking the picture for the larger resolution shows better just how well these games have aged -- T H A N K Y O U, all of you who contribute to retro emulator work.