# What happens if there is a tie for Screenshot of the Week?

Tags: support, screenshot-of-the-week, screenshot-widget

I'm not sure if this has happened before, but I'd like to know what happens if two answers have an equal amount of upvotes when the voting period ends. Also, I'm curious how this affects the widget on the main Arqade site.

Comment: Anything else would be very hard to enforce.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When we've had ties in the past, we simply declare the two or more users as winners and the next Screenshot of the Week post will note that.  Here is an example: [Screenshot of Week #51](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16136/screenshot-of-week-51)

As for the widget, we (the Arqade Mods) put one of winners screenshot up for one week, and the other winners the next week (since it's a two week period between changing the widget).

Comment: We had a tie also on [Screenshot of the Week #111](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17045/screenshot-of-the-week-111-favourite-companion)!