# Screenshot of the Week #111 - Favourite Companion

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest is over.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17035/screenshot-of-the-week-110) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17059/screenshot-of-the-week-112-small-but-powerful)*

Hello and welcome to the **111<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to both the winners of the previous contest! [Neonit](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17037/87579)'s picture from [fallout-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fallout-4)

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

and [Joachim](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17042/87579)'s picture from [a-plague-tale-innocence](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-plague-tale-innocence) won with 9 upvotes!
[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](//arqade.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2024-03-18, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2024-03-25, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Favourite Companion

This can be any companion; from loyal animal companions, an odd couple entwined eternal in an unpredictable world, to an android friend follower, equally invested in your shared escapades, giving ever-welcome bites of sage advice and backup muscle just when you really need it... and everything in between!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](//meta.arqade.com/q/15029).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](//meta.arqade.com/q/14939) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Comment: "Hey... listen!"

Comment: It looks so short in comparison. 

Comment: "How about we explore the area ahead of us later?"

Comment: @FabianRöling we said _favorite_.

Comment: So... Does it mean GLaDOS isn't qualified?

Comment: I missed my own suggestion! Oh well. I enjoyed scrolling the answers though, some of them I've never heard of.

Comment: @n00dles you are still in time to submit one :)

Comment: oops xD I thought it was annotated because it had finished lol. Damn :)

Comment: @n00dles I'm eager to see what you intended to submit for edition #112

Comment: @n00dles we usually repeat the themes, you can always try the next run!

Comment: Yeah, I didn't have anything "special" though, but I have over 10,000 pics on my PS4 that should be used for _something_ xD. I could prob find at least one for any situation. (Damn "Photo Mode"!)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Our pal Wheatley from [portal-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/portal-2) telling you to jump down a collapsed stairwell

[image: Wheatley!]

Answer (score 10):

Who are better companions than Donkey and Diddy? Here playing Switch on [donkey-kong-country-tropical-freeze](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donkey-kong-country-tropical-freeze)

[image]

Comment: Is this an idle animation?

Comment: @User23415 yes, only when Diddy is on Donkey's back

Answer (score 9):

[image: Mir'licia Rathror with Fran in Final Fantasy XIV]

My Wind-up Fran Minion in [final-fantasy-xiv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-xiv) who's been by my side since day 1 of my adventures in Eorzea. while i have plenty of other Minions, it just never feels right replace her

Comment: I thought I saw Riku from Kingdom Hearts for some reasons. Or Bayonetta.

Comment: FFXII is forever my favorite.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe not entirely in the spirit of the theme, but my favorite companions are my kids playing [sea-of-thieves](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sea-of-thieves) with me:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image: midna]

Midna and link in wolf mode

[zelda-twilight-princess](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-twilight-princess)

Answer (score 5):

"This one's for you, Teddy!" [backyard-baseball-1997](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backyard-baseball-1997)

[image: Luanne Lui gives her pink teddy bear a hug as she steps up to bat in Backyard Baseball (1997). Amir Khan waits on the pitcher's mound.]

Comment: **GOAT** game!!

Answer (score 4):

Atto saying "Thank you" to Milli in the game [clockwork](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clockwork) for giving him some time to rest, despite their tight timetable.

[image: A screenshot of a steampunk looking environment. The main character is a young mechanical boy called Atto. He can be seen saying thank you to the spirit from within his clock named Milli.]

Comment: Was this the inspiration behind your username, perchance?

Comment: @Joachim One of them, yeah. [This](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7371/the-many-usernames-of-sff-se/13612#13612) was the other inspiration.

Answer (score 3):

[image]
So Sidon's avatar **does** swim in [zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom)!

Comment: I don't typically play with pro HUD on, as you can see with this image. Is it permissible to use a magic eraser tool to remove UI elements not present with pro HUD enabled?

Comment: Yes, limited picture modifications are allowed