# Screenshot of the Week #112 - Small but powerful [Submissions Closed. Vote Now!]

Tags: discussion, featured, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## Submissions Closed. Vote Now!

Hello and welcome to the **112<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [GammaGames](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17056/87579)' picture from [portal-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/portal-2) won with 11 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](//arqade.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2024-04-01, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2024-04-08, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Small but powerful

Post a screenshot showing a pint-sized character that packs a surprising punch.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](//meta.arqade.com/q/15029).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](//meta.arqade.com/q/14939) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Comment: Was this week's theme an answer in the Theme Thread? I thought we were going over the themes presented therein, most upvoted first, and that that was its function? And that generally the themes are alternated with themeless SotWs. Not that I mind, mind, just wondering what the process was.

Comment: @Joachim yep, [of course it is](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16278/87579)!  I don't have a real rule, I've seen that mods used random suggestions also for past contests, so I usually choose one from the unused and most upvoted. And we had a lot of themeless events, so I try to pick a theme when possibile.

Comment: Do we have a "protocol" to follow? In that case, my bad

Comment: I don't know. We never established one. We can get away with anything :) (And sorry, I completely missed seeing it!)

Comment: @Joachim no worries! I like the alternated theme and themeless, we should keep it that way

Comment: That screenshot was from April 2011! My other shot would've broken spoiler rules 

Answer (score 10):

The game over screen when you lose against Ado in the "boss butch" mode in [kirby-dream-land-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kirby-dream-land-3).

[image: Kirby is standing still as Ado is painting over his face, seemingly displeased by it, whilst Ado seems to be enjoying it.]

This may be a bit of a stretch though. I posted this because in the game, Ado is quite small and weak/is defeated as soon as you get in physical contact, but has incredible painting skills: anything Ado paints will come to life to fight against Kirby, and each painted creatures count as a boss on their own.

Comment: If if turns out it's not a fit for the theme, I'll be deleting my post.

Comment: I'm still unsure if Ado is supposed to be a boy or a girl, or if Ado is supposed to be Adeleine who appears in subsequent Kirby games.

Comment: Kirby is a perfect representation of the theme!

Answer (score 8):

At least he apologized...
A cute (and deadly) Tonberry from [final-fantasy-viii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-viii)

[image]

Comment: Ah yes, the giant Tonberry from FF VIII that shrinks to a very tiny size

Answer (score 5):

[mincraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mincraft-java-edition) 1.21 adds the perfect new features for this contest:

- the `scale` attribute, which can make the player huge or tiny
- the "mace", a hammer that does more damage the harder you smash down onto someone, proportional to your fall distance
- the `gravity` attribute, which makes you fall faster or slower, but does not affect things that are fall distance dependent, like mace damage
- in yesterday's snapshot also the "Density" enchantment for maces that makes them do even more damage per fallen block

Combining all of that and giving a mace Damage 255 via command lets me one-hit kill a Warden (500 health points) with a single jump and hit. Being tiny while doing that just adds to the humour. Less gravity made me jump higher and also gave me more time to take the screenshot, to see all those glorious damage particles up close. I look even smaller due to wide FOV. I could make it even wider with various methods, but that would make the image too distorted
One-hit killing any boss is also possible in Survival, but usually you have to fall so far and fast that it is really difficult to hit the boss. And if you miss, you die.

[image: tiny Minecraft character murdering gigantic Warden]

Comment: I was wondering why the submission had disappeared. You were actually preparing a more refined version.

Comment: The amount of damage particles is absurd, I've never seen anything close to this in previous versions.

Comment: They are usually a pretty subtle effect. I barely ever consciously notice them when playing. But of course in this case… "THAT'S A LOTTA DAMAGE!" ;) I think it is actually capped to the Warden's health, the cheaty weapon might be able to produce even more.