# Screenshot of the Week #74 - Inventory

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16516) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16538)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **74<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Faither's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16519/222022) picture from [mirrors-edge-catalyst](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mirrors-edge-catalyst) won with 9 upvotes (but what a cliffhanger it was!)!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2022-09-26, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2022-10-03, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Inventory

This week's theme is [inventory](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15098/222022).
Immense stacks of potions, a pet, a fancy hat, trivial trinkets, mountains of gold, that one weapon-that-will-be-extremely-useful-in-that-very-particular-situation: show us what you got!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Comment: This submission of mine would probably quality: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15232/171580 But I'll just make a screenshot of a double chest plus inventory full of beacons and Nether stars that I've gathered on a Survival server, as soon as I'm on my computer. I had something similar here before, but since then I got a lot more and now it's more fitting.

Comment: @FabianRöling It would. There are no restrictions as to where you keep your inventory :)

Comment: I just noticed that you copypasted the old dates and didn't update them. 

Comment: @Neonit Thanks, updated! :)

Comment: FYI - in case you get to it first... we normally do a Halloween theme around this time of the year. If I looked at the calendar right, the 17th through 31st should probably be that contest

Comment: @TimmyJim My self-written mail notification system filters out a bunch of common greetings, but I guess I went a bit too far, because for a moment I thought you wanted to see sausages: "we normally do a ween theme…"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Back in the days when I wandered the Captial Wasteland, I figured that – in order to remain liquid and to not miss something – I could go on the super safe side and just pick everything up. Everywhere. (Except where I would have to steal.) In hindsight I haven't sold much of it.

I decided to exhibit a sample of the everything in my Megaton house.

[image: Fallout 3 Megaton Home with loot piles]

*I cannot reach my fridge anymore. Could anyone be so kind and bring me some BlamCo Mac & Cheese or an Iguana-on-a-stick? I can pay you 2,000 bent tin cans. Or 100 teddy bears?*

[fallout-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fallout-3)

Comment: Ten Nuka-Cola Quantum and you've got yourself a deal

Comment: The issue here is that they are in the fridge.

Comment: I don't recall Moira selling the Hoarder Theme, must have missed that...

Comment: At least the bobble head collection is well kept.

Comment: That's not healthy, friend: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compulsive_hoarding .

Comment: How did you get a photo of my 3yrs old closet?

Comment: Back in Ultima 7 you could actually load the magic carpet you would find near a dungeon entrance to the west of Britain with chests. My carpet quickly became a cargo... I remember loading a full chest just with deer meat from Yew forest,  while another was full of gold ingots, nuggets and gems waiting to be converted into coins (something that never happened since the game didn't exactly give you many reasons to buy stuff, the best items you would usually find in dungeons and such)

Answer (score 9):

The many, many crafting supplies I've hoarded in [the-witcher-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-witcher-3)

[image: Witcher image]

Comment: Oh yeah, from some point onward it takes a while for especially that tab to load..

Comment: Is that raw meat to replenish health?

Comment: @LoreFriendly yes - you don't eat raw meat?

Comment: @TimmyJim Medium-rare mostly. :-)

Answer (score 8):

Lots of loot in as close a pile as we could get it... the good old days of [sea-of-thieves](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sea-of-thieves), before we got bored with it :')

[image]

Comment: Got a price tag on what that all reeled in?

Comment: @TimmyJim sorry pal, this one is from a few years ago, I couldn't tell you anymore LOL

Comment: It looks ..underwhelming for someone not familiar with the game. Can you tell us what the pile consists of?

Comment: It's hard to make out, but there's a good 20 skulls in that pile. They're dropped by Skeleton pirates and captains, or gotten from quests. We spent probably 3 hours or so farming it all up, and although I don't know how much it was worth, it was definitely a fair bit of gold and status with the Order of Souls!

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Gary might have [10 of the 8 badges](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3444/1651), but I doubt he has completed the Pokedex in [pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green)

Answer (score 6):

A *slight* upgrade to [my #70 submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16485/171580):

[image: double chest of beacons, inventory with stars, skulls and diamonds]

On the [minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition) server I play on, I currently own 3554 beacons, 1771 Nether stars, 2009 Wither skeleton skulls, 1259 diamonds, 457 enchanting tables, 792 shulker shells, many shulker boxes everywhere and over 1.3 million bonemeal. Enderpearls, Netherrack, arrows and blackstone already  overflow my storage for them.
I even have an item filter for dragon eggs, because I have two accounts whitelisted and the dragon kill advancement gives a dragon egg on that server, so I had one for the item frame and one for the hopper. But of course it has never actually filtered anything, it's just there to brag. :D
I also have 6760 hours=40 weeks in the play time scoreboard, but the majority of that is AFK time of the account on the right in the screenshot.
The only thing I'm not at all rich in is Netherite, because that requires actual effort. :D But I wouldn't use it for tools and armour anyway, getting maximally enchanted diamond armour from villagers and just replacing it when I lose my items is much easier.
I have automatic farms for almost all automatically farmable (and useful) resources, so most of my item types are free to take for anyone on the server. I also have a free Nether tunnel building service, which over time lead to so many so complex tunnel systems being built by me that I created three map arts for all their destinations. And those aren't even close to the best map arts I've built on that server. Once we have a fitting theme, I'll submit the truly amazing ones here. ;)

Comment: Actually, I have more beacons, I didn't count the placed ones. They are all over the place. I even covered the entire island around spawn with all beacon effects.

Comment: I thought I had a hoarding problem :-P

Comment: Hoarding is good in Minecraft, because you never know when you need a lot of something. It happens very often on that server that someone digs a giant hole, keeps many double chests of stone, then a few weeks later someone else wanted to build something huge and needs that much stone.

Comment: @FabianRöling - I have this issue with dirt on my friend's server. Noone stores it so when I try and build an underground farm or something I'm constantly running out of dirt :')

Comment: @Robotnik At least they're not wasting a finite resource: https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Dirt#Renewable_acquisition

Answer (score 6):

Ready to loot the town in Escape from Pavlov! [Bonus shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOdCD.png) of the town, because it gave me a nice Salem's Lot vibe that fits the season  [pavlov-vr](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pavlov-vr)

[image: Pavlov VR inventory]

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm seeing here. A character with a gun…?

Comment: ..and a Tupperware box with trail mix?

Comment: Ah, fair. Pavlov is a virtual reality game, you can see my floating hands holding the gun. Items are stored on your vest and I'm looking down in this image. I've got some boxes of ammo (left is pistol, green container behind it is sniper, rounded white lid is shotgun, far right is rifle), a flashlight, and two bottles of pills for healing.

Answer (score 0):

Never have I seen so many players led into battle by such a powerful character. This user has changed their name since this screenshot was taken so I though it was appropriate to keep it unblurred as it really suits the situation. The two arrows through their face were fired by me and should have killed him but somehow he lived.

[image: Father protecting children]

Comment: Hi Christopher, thank you for your contribution, but as you can see in both the title and the body of this thread, this Screenshot of the Week is no longer accepting submissions. Moreover, as the guidelines point out, the screenshot has to be your own, and yours also doesn't appear to comply to the theme of this week ("Inventory"). This SotW will end this evening, however, so you can submit a new screenshot in our following contest soon.