# Screenshot of the Week #75

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest is over.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16529) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16558)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **75<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Neonit's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16532/8350) picture from [fallout-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fallout-3) won with 15 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2022-10-10, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2022-10-17, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## No Theme

There's no theme this week, so just send us the best you've got!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Comment: HAHA TAKE THAT @Joachim! Us lazy mods finally woke up early enough to beat you to this for once! MODS: 1 JOACHIM: 100!

Comment: Mods 0.5 then, I'll take it

Comment: I'm overflowing with shame and defeat.

Comment: Considering how many times we've posted it days late (before @Joachim started picking up all our slack), I figured a few hours earlier just averages out to only a day late!

Comment: More like mods 0.25, because the mentioned Halloween theme is also missing. And there are already non-Halloween submissions, so it can't even be added retroactively.

Comment: @FabianRöling next contest should be the halloween one as that comment said on the previous post - not this one.  The timing of the next contest would end on Halloween Day so it would be perfect!

Comment: Shouldn't this be "Dragon hoard", not "Dragon horde"?  A horde is a large loosely organized warhost of dragons (though 'flight' would be a more common term).  A Dragon hoard is a pile of treasure owned by a Dragon.

Comment: @aphid Very good point! **Calling all mods**: can that be adjusted in the widget?

Answer (score 14):

[image]

Enjoying the view in [gears-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gears-5)

Comment: *Paramount Pictures presents*

Answer (score 13):

I share the feelings of the [Overwatch 1 post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16545/), and it will be fondly missed.

Currently, the game is 90% queue time and "unexpected error" during matches.

But, enjoy a screenshot of the ceramic tiles found in the Esperança map:
[image: Tiles in Esperança map]

Despite all the negative aspects, there's Esperança (hope) that things will improve soon.

(Btw, the new maps are absolutely awesome.)

Answer (score 11):

[image]

---

[mirrors-edge-catalyst](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mirrors-edge-catalyst)

Answer (score 10):

A friend and I have been *productive* during the long weekend (Germany) in [satisfactory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/satisfactory).

[image: Professional factory layout in Satisfactory]

*No matter where I am or what I'm looking for – chances are good it's riding past me on a belt within 5 meters.*

Comment: This game blows my mind, I could barely play Factorio!

Comment: @GammaGames You mean, because it's easier with 2 dimensions? I haven't played Factorio, but from what I saw, I think it is even more complex.

Comment: It's easier to wrap my head around 2D yeah, even if the systems in Factorio might be more complex. I more meant that I'm in awe of people that can build *this* and keep track of it

Comment: Factorio is 100% more complex.  Satisfactory I thought was much more straightforward (while still being amazing!).  Factorio is fantastic as well, but definitely harder, especially if you have enemies enabled/not friendly.

Comment: I agree with Timmy, Factorio can and will get wayyy beyond what you (unless of course you force it) do in Satisfactory.

Answer (score 8):

In memory of [overwatch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overwatch) 1. One of the few instances where joining during the end of match screen actually produces a scenic view. (Slightly cropped because I didn't hide UI and Discord overlay was visible.)

[image: Overwatch Oasis map]

Comment: RIP Overwatch...

Answer (score 7):

Bloodflies hatching and swarming in an abandoned house in Karnaca in [dishonored-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dishonored-2).

[image: Bloodflies on my trail]

Answer (score 5):

[image: More Power!]

*What do you mean with "we ran out of power"? I just built eight new coal generators!*

The classic struggles of [satisfactory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/satisfactory)

Comment: My friend ALWAYS does this to me - both in this game and Factorio.  I'll build some power generating structures, and then 10 minutes later a fuse blows because they decided to build a way over the top Manufactures facility that eats all the power I just added and then some!!!

Comment: Well right now it kinda works, though of everything was active we'd use more than double our current production. I really need to get those fuel generators done

Answer (score 5):

[image: Metalkingslime]

please, please, please don't run away. [dragon-quest-8](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-quest-8)

Comment: Is that a king metal slime? If so, I very much hope it did not run away, it is rare enough even getting to see one.

Comment: Yes it is a king metal slime and i defeat him.

Comment: Wow I got a shot from 5 liquid metal slime.