# Screenshot of the Week #76 - Halloween

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest is over.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16538) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16580)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **76<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Batophobia's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16540/163757) picture from [gears-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gears-5) won with 14 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2022-10-24, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2022-10-31, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Halloween

It is that time of year again! Post a screenshot of your favorite festive Halloween-themed moment!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Would you step into the circle in the lobby of [phasmophobia](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phasmophobia)?

[image]

Answer (score 12):

This speaks for itself.

[image]

---

[minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition)

Comment: Reminds me of LiveOverflow's Minecraft intro.

Comment: Of course also with pumpkins. :D

Comment: @FabianRöling Lots! I made sure! Also, as I'm not that familiar with Minecraft: I had made the letters mostly out of snow (because it's white and fits the Arqade logo as well as the theme), and then I wanted to put in the pumpkin lanterns to light the letters up. You probably know what happened next, but I was quite surprised to find the things came alive, also perfectly in line with what I was doing and for what I was doing it :D

Comment: You even figured out how to avoid it, which many people don't know: Placing the pumpkin first.

Answer (score 11):

My little oob-gang in their costumes!

[ooblets](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ooblets)

[image: ooblets]

Comment: Your gang looks sweet.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Enjoying the Halloween challenge in [dungeon-defenders-awakened](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeon-defenders-awakened)

Answer (score 6):

[image: halloween-town] Arrival in halloween town in [kingdom-hearts-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom-hearts-2)

Comment: Funnily enough, I posted the same thing for [last years](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16124/124566) Halloween SOTW

Comment: Oh, I didn't know. This was my first thought for this theme.

Comment: @Wondercricket LOL thats funny :P

Comment: Please don't close it as duplicate 

Comment: @nobody 1) You can't close questions as being dups :P 2) There's nothing wrong with the post, I was simply pointing out that it was funny. Your submission is well within the rules

Comment: It was a joke  @Wondercricket

Comment: @Wondercricket That's "answers" :)

Answer (score 6):

[wizard101](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wizard101) loading screen:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Me and a friend during the All Saints Wake event in [final-fantasy-14](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-14) transformed as Nashu Mhakaracca (myself) and Hildibrand Manderville (them) doing the Manderville dance with The Great Gourd

Answer (score 6):

All spooked up at the Abyss bar in [deep-rock-galactic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-rock-galactic)
[image: Ghosts, pumpkins, bats, and cobwebs cover decorate the space rig bar.]

Answer (score 3):

Another [phasmophobia](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phasmophobia) submission for the Spooky Update. Just a casual ghost event featuring a ghost wearing a Jack-o' lantern for a hat.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

A new update just dropped in [overwatch-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overwatch-2).

Really hard content, and fun!
The server issues are back though...

[image: Junkenstein's Revenge: Wrath of the Bride]

Comment: You submitted this after the submission period!!! But we shall allow it :)

Comment: @TimmyJim ... I REALLY didn't notice it. Thank you for allowing it. Sadly, all this content came just less than 10 minutes before I posted. Banner blindness is real, and I fell for it. If you want, I can delete it.

Comment: not its fine leave it ! Its not a strict rule really.  Its more for organizing the community event.

Answer (score 2):

My Jack O’ Lantern-themed [gta-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gta-online) character:

[image: screenshot of Jack O’ Lantern-themed GTA Online character]

*I had to collect 200 (!) [Jack O’ Lantern collectibles](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Jack_O%E2%80%99_Lanterns) within one day to get that t-shirt.*

Comment: There's a pumpkin on every one of the four submissions so far. :D

Comment: it is the symbol for halloween.

Comment: Or skeletons or ghosts or other monsters or candy or …

Comment: @FabianRöling All 5 currently! Let's keep this up!

Comment: @Joachim I thought the [latest one](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16567/171580) was without pumpkins, but nope, there are some in the background on the right. :D

Comment: @FabianRöling I made sure to capture them ;)