# Screenshot of the Week #77

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest is over.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16558) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16604)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **77<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Timmy Jim's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16567/163757) picture from [phasmophobia](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phasmophobia) won with 13 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2022-11-07, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2022-11-14, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## No Theme

There is no theme for this contest.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of Alexandria Hypatia's examination rooms in the Addermire Institute in [dishonored-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dishonored-2).

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Take a break to relax.  Spread your wings and soak up some sun.  [yooka-laylee](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yooka-laylee)

[image]

Comment: Those sunglasses don't look like they're very good at blocking the sun!

Answer (score 4):

So many loot bugs in one spot. It's a shame they all have to die. [deep-rock-galactic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-rock-galactic)
[image: Seven loot bugs next to each other.]

Comment: ROCK AND STONE BRUTHA

Answer (score 3):

Who remember him?

[image]

[klonoa](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/klonoa)

Answer (score 3):

My [gta-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gta-online) character spent Halloween drunk dancing after being [abducted by a UFO](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Sightseeing) (wearing a UFO-themed cap and boxer shorts that he got after being abducted).

[image: drunk dancing after being abducted by a UFO]

Answer (score 3):

Trains man, they always get me. Getting run over shortly after setting up the first train of the map in [factorio](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/factorio)

[image: Death by Train]

Answer (score 2):

Got an fun shot while playing some Halo mods in [contractors-vr](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contractors-vr)!

[image: halo-the-pit]

Comment: I don't know what I'm seeing there. Well, I do know what I'm seeing with normal screen brightness: Black. :D

Comment: @FabianRöling  it’s a bit easier to see in the headset, I tweaked the photo a bit so you can see the enemy I’m getting the drop on a bit better