# Screenshot of the Week #78 - Three Years of Screenshot of the Week: Celebration!

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest is over.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16580) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16614)*

---

Hello and welcome to a special edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Joachim's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16596/163757) picture from [dishonored-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dishonored-2) won with 8 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

### Now for the "special edition" part...

This week marks **three years** of doing Screenshot of the Week.   It's been a long time now since we began running this community event, with the [first week](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14741/screenshot-of-the-week-contest-1) happening three years ago now. Its been a blast seeing all the images over the years.

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2022-11-21, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2022-11-28, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Celebration, Victory, Partying, Winning, etc.!

It seems fitting to try out a theme centered around celebrating/big moments for three years of Screenshot of the Week.  Try and post a screenshot related to a momentous celebration or victory, a big party, a massive win, or just something awesome!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Comment: It has already been 3 years?!

Comment: Surely it was only 77 weeks, right? ;)

Comment: The aspect ratio on the winning screenshot looks niiiice in the sidebar

Comment: @GammaGames I concur

Comment: If I submit a 1:100 ratio screenshot, can people please vote for it for software testing purposes? :P

Comment: Hi ! Are the submitters required to give a precise description, as seen in the two submission ? Is there a submission format ?

Comment: @AbduRahman descriptions aren't really necessary. The only thing I ask for is the game tag is included.  We've had submissions before that are simply a screenshot with a game tag.

Comment: Could people post their back-story on how they achieved this screenshot. AlThough it may be inconvenient.

Comment: @AbduRahman you can if you wish! There really isn't any strict rules other than the screenshot be from a video game.

Comment: @AbduRahman I find descriptions to be useful when the image content isn't particularly obvious to people who haven't played the game. Lengthier explanations are especially appreciated when it's about a very lucky or difficult to achieve moment.

Comment: Can we put this 'week''s theme under [Victory](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15060/222022), or is it worth having its own theme (if at all)?

Comment: @Joachim I wanted this to be more like "celebrations" but usually "victories" involve celebrations so I clumped them together.  I _originally_ wanted to do a "Best of the Screenshot of the Week" where the theme would have been to go back through the last 77 posts and choose your favorite screenshot, but I didn't know how that would be received.  It be kind of weird if you chose a screenshot other than your own to submit.

Comment: Unless we make that a rule. But a thread like that might still be worth considering, independent of other celebrations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Noah and Mio staring off into a beautiful sunset after a major victory, both in-game and emotionally in [xenoblade-chronicles-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xenoblade-chronicles-3)

[image: Noah and Mio looking into the sunset]

Answer (score 7):

Major victory after activating the swamp laser in [the-witness](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-witness)

[image]

Comment: The more I read, the more I learn: https://www.reddit.com/r/TheWitness/comments/47mt4t/

Comment: The visual easter egg here is that the women are reaching for each other (not you). https://i.imgur.com/X3plQml.png

Comment: Once again, this (excellent) game make me feel like an blundering idiot (and it's probably true).

Answer (score 5):

Finally managed to launch the first rocket in [factorio](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/factorio) with the Space Exploration mod. Now to explore the depths of space itself...

[image: The Achievement for launching the first rocket popping up]

Answer (score 5):

Yuna performs the last sending after beating sin an ju yevon in [final-fantasy-10](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-10)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Celebration == the most colourful screenshot I could find among my hundreds:

[image]

The tower of Goldilocks and 'Jack's' beanstalk dominating the Land of a Thousand Fables in [the-witcher-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-witcher-3). And there is a rainbow!