# Screenshot of the Week #79

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This Contest is Over.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16604) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16623)*

---

Hello and welcome to the 79th Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Wondercricket's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16605/163757) picture from [xenoblade-chronicles-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xenoblade-chronicles-3) won with 9 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2022-12-05, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2022-12-12, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## No Theme

There is no theme this week.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[image: A tranquil village scene in Dorfromantik]

Another day, another charming village created in [dorfromantik](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dorfromantik)

Comment: Quite colorful.  What do you do in this game?

Comment: It's a tile-laying game. You add hexagonal tiles to your village, trying to match the edges to existing tiles as well as possible and completing quests such as "make a contiguous forest of 300+ trees."

Comment: Just tried out this game today and it is so satisfying! Very Carcassonne-esque.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Heartwarming portrait in [bug-fables](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug-fables)

Answer (score 8):

Tried out a horror game called [the-beast-inside](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-beast-inside), and while it's nothing particularly groundbreaking, it does have the occasional pretty scene:

[image]

EDIT: sidenote, don't bother playing this game. It just gets worse as it goes on. It takes mechanics from lots of other horror games, and does them all pretty poorly. I didn't bother finishing it, and actually rage-uninstalled it.

Still pretty at times tho.

Answer (score 5):

[kingdom-hearts-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom-hearts-2)
He said he defeated Rikku

[image: beat]

That is exactly what I did. Whissle.

Comment: This is one franchise I have not played. But I added it to my list :-)

Comment: When I played it and it comes to this scene I was laughing.

Comment: @LoreFriendly You're in for a wild ride

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Endgame in [cat-poke](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cat-poke)

Answer (score 3):

- We find a new enemy
- We use the Battle Scope
- We miss with the Battle Scope?

[image: Trails from Zero - The Battle Scope can miss!]

[trails-from-zero](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trails-from-zero)

Comment: This is the game I bought for me as Christmas present 

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Reunited blacksmith brothers Brok (Brokkr) and Sindri (Eitri), sons of Ivaldi, talking business with Kratos and Atreus - Brok gives his thoughts on the Dvegræðikr, dwarven armour of legend. [god-of-war-2018](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/god-of-war-2018)

Comment: This is Ragnorak yes?

Comment: No, sorry I forgot to mention this is God of War (2018) on the PS4.

Comment: On PC it is just _God of War_ (only released for PC in 2022 I believe). I played through this very part just the other week, it's for one of the last quests in the game.