# Screenshot of the Week #80 - Happy Holidays 2022!

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest is over.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16614) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16631)*

---

Hello and welcome to the 80th Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [DLosc's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16618/163757) picture from [dorfromantik](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dorfromantik) won with 16 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2022-12-19, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2022-12-26, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Christmas/Holidays

The season-appropriate theme for this week is **Christmas** or more broadly, **Holidays**. We're looking for whatever the festive-holiday season means to you: family, friends, fun hats or decorations, give us the best seasonal content you have!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Comment: It seems people are taking these holidays very seriously: only two answers this far..

Comment: @Joachim my pc is down atm so I can't really play any games :(

Comment: That sucks, sorry to hear it. Down for repairs, down for upgrades, down with a virus (pun?), burned down?

Comment: @Joachim I thought my GPU was having power issues, so I RMAed it, but the manufacturer found no issues with it. So I am currently waiting for it to ship back to me. My computer was turning 100% off whenever the gpu went under load. So I assumed it was something with the GPU. But, I guess it could also be the power supply. So I bought a new one of those also.  GPU isn't expected back until the 20th :(

Comment: @Joachim If it was a virus: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/0g12hmnGD00

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

Dreaming of a white holiday season in [horizon-zero-dawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-zero-dawn)

Answer (score 9):

Sitting down resting next to the Christmas tree in [valheim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/valheim).

[image: valheim christmas tree]

Comment: I haven't really played Valheim since before Hearth and Home. Is it worth trying to get back into again? Not sure my friends will, so how's the solo experience?

Comment: @nightsurfer the Mistlands update is finally out so that's why I am replaying it with friends. It's definitely more enjoyable with friends, I've only really played with friends apart from just logging on to our dedicated server to farm resources solo, which can be relaxing at least.

Answer (score 7):

It's too bad they didn't put the Nutcracker Suite music in the jukebox.
[image: Gunner Dwarf dancing like a Swan Lake ballerina.]
[deep-rock-galactic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-rock-galactic)

Answer (score 5):

Hugo lighting candles in [a-plague-tale-innocence](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-plague-tale-innocence)

[image]