# Screenshot of the Week #81

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest is over.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16623) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16650)*

---

Hello and welcome to the 81st Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Batophobia's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16624/163757) picture from [horizon-zero-dawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-zero-dawn) won with 12 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2023-01-02, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2023-01-09 we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## No Theme

There is no theme this week.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Comment: "We will accept submissions for a week, **until** 19:00 UTC of **2022-12-26** [...]" <-- I think you meant "until [...] 2023-01-02"?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel yes. Not the first time I've messed that up!

Answer (score 13):

Cannot handle the cuteness in [stray](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stray)

[image]

Comment: I see cats, I must upvote.

Comment: Oh good to know 

Answer (score 8):

Alterna's panoramic view from [splatoon-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/splatoon-3)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Master Kohga...
[image: Hyrule Warriors: Age of Calamity]

Anyone else think the sanity of this guy is questionable?

Comment: Questionable is an understatement

Comment: At least he leaves little leeway for misinterpretation.

Comment: Sigh... I'm being beaten by cats.

Answer (score 6):

Found on an outer planet, as a soccer ball spaceship, in [xkcd's Gravity](https://xkcd.com/2712/):

[image]

Comment: Is this a videogame?

Comment: Well, it is a mini-game where you fly around in space and explore planets, embedded in a webcomic, so... yes?

Comment: Dang that spaceship is hard to control.

Answer (score 4):

Our hall we built up in [valheim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/valheim).

[image: Our hall we built up in [tag:valheim]]

Answer (score 3):

What happend here? [the-white-chamber](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-white-chamber)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ah, [cyberpunk2077](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cyberpunk2077), please don't change...

[image: V's body and Johnny Silverhand]

This is 100% not supposed to happen.

If you sneak into the developer's easter egg room, when you sit, it spawns V's body (without a head, so it doesn't cover the camera).
This might be possible on versions 1.06 and older, but it's also possible with freecam mods on newer versions.

Also, if you pick female V, and talk to vendors as Johnny Silverhand, the game will use the male V's voice.

Comment: OK now I am curious, but where is this room and how do I sneak into it and does this still happen with patch 1.61?

Comment: @LoreFriendly You can find how to get to that room on Google. Some people like the exploration and that's why I'm not sharing it here. It isn't possible since version 1.12, where the slide bug was fixed. Back then, you could slide and jump off of a building, and when you hit the ground, all fall damage was cancelled and you would live. If you're in the Arasaka building, and jumped off of the building, you could probably live and sneak into the room.