# Screenshot of the Week #82

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest is over.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16631) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16658)*

---

Hello and welcome to the 82nd Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Batophobia's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16635/87579) picture from [stray](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stray) won with 12 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2023-01-16, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2023-01-23 we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## No Theme

There is no theme this week.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Comment: I hope it's ok if I posted this

Comment: Of course. Anyone can!

Comment: The mod always appreciate it when someone else picks up our slack.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[image]

Love the views in [xenoblade-chronicles-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xenoblade-chronicles-3)

Comment: This game was absolutely beautiful

Answer (score 11):

Into the belly of the beast… [god-of-war-2018](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/god-of-war-2018)

[image: Kratos and Atreus headed into the World Serpent]

Answer (score 8):

I'm not in your city! Why can't you just leave me alone?
[image]

[zelda-breath-of-the-wild](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-breath-of-the-wild)

Comment: Just like in real life 

Answer (score 7):

Sephiroth's iconic fiery scene in [crisis-core-final-fantasy-7-reunion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crisis-core-final-fantasy-7-reunion)

[image: Sephiroth in from of flames]

Comment: Oh made similar shot in FF7 on switch.

Answer (score 6):

A planet-freezing space station from the completely over the top [prodeus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prodeus)

[image]

Comment: I picked this up last week, and I'm absolutely loving it. Complete gem of a game. Must play for any fans of retro shooters.

Comment: It's retro without the woes of the era (looking at Blood: Fresh Supply, which I hated, refunded, and bought this instead LOL)

Comment: Dusk is another really great retro one. Worth checking out if you haven't already played it: https://store.steampowered.com/app/519860/DUSK/

Comment: Loved Dusk! AMID EVIL is excellent as well. Pretty much anything New Blood has their name on, actually...

Answer (score 5):

yorda saves the horned boy in[ico](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ico)

[image: yorda]

Answer (score 4):

LIGHT WARRIORS??
I, Garland, will knock you all down!!

[image]

[final-fantasy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy)

Comment: I don't think animated pictures are allowed. They would at least be very distracting if they ended up in the sidebar.

Comment: I'm unsure if the sidebar would even allow an animated .gif to begin with, but agree with Fabian.

Comment: It's cool. Sorry for breaking the rules (or, possibly inspiring a new one).

Comment: It's not explicitly stated in the rules. A .gif is an image. Whether or not it works in the sidebar shouldn't be a determinant. If animations are to be ruled out, we should just update the rules before the next contest.

Comment: @TimmyJim I have tested the sidebar with GIF and APNG animations and both seem to work. I don't think we'd need a rules update, but I do seem to recall some mention of a possibility of an animation/GIF contest theme at one point. The animation was a bit of a distraction in the sidebar. Maybe an extra step of making the image static but the target of the click be the animated image would work. I'm not sure how much work that is with the widget controls or if it offers that option. I see the HTML `img` and `a href` tags are already separate, so it's theoretically possible.

Comment: @BoogaRoo enlightening! It would have to be taken up with SE Staff to see how it could be implemented. An animated gif contest would be cool to do though.

Comment: @TimmyJim This might not be the best place to discuss this, but I will leave my suggestion anyways: If you have control on what image shows there, you could ask the O.P. to pick the perfect frame to show in the widget. Or, everybody provides 2 images - an animated and the frame, but that may be quite a waste of space in imgur's servers... And this would be the only exception to the rule of posting 2 images.

Comment: I'll just chime in here again: even though I submitted this(these) screenshot(s), I agree this kind of thing would be horribly distracting in the sidebar. The late 90's were a fun time, but animated GIFs and the HTML marquee were not the high points of that era. On the other hand, a contest that was all about animated gifs could be fun to do.