# Screenshot of the Week #102 - Halloween

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest is over.

*[previous contest](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16921) | [next contest](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16943)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **102<sup>nd</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Artfaith's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16926/127901) picture from [elder-scrolls-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elder-scrolls-online) won with 10 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2023-11-06, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2023-11-13, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Halloween

It is that time of year again! Post a screenshot of your favorite festive Halloween-themed moment!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Photo Booth in [ooblets](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ooblets)

[image: Photo Booth]

Comment: Thank you... The composition, shades, and action flow! An ineffably wonderful work... It's always hard to say it, but it feels perfect... So warm also... and heartfelt...

Comment: Thank you! The poses are random afaik, though I did take some time getting the costumes ready and spent a few hundred gummies trying to get decent picture  I'm glad it's enjoyed!

Answer (score 11):

Oh no... not this [again](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16567/163757)! [phasmophobia](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phasmophobia)

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I was too scared to take a better picture
[phasmophobia](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phasmophobia)

[image: red skull in the sky]

Comment: Just like our Halloween-themed Screenshot of the Week (and, well, several SotWs before that, as well as many status updates), this was posted appropriately late. +1!

Comment: @Joachim I prefer the term "fashionably late"

Answer (score 4):

Deep Cut trio in their Halloween costumes from [splatoon-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/splatoon-3), or actually, Splatoween

[image: Splatoween]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Treating a medical emergency in [roblox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roblox) (Emergency Hamburg)

Comment: Hi there, I'm not really seeing how this is Halloween themed.  Additionally, your image should be uploaded via the image uploader (seems like you embedded an HTML image element instead).

Comment: @TimmyJim 1. Dying is scary, so it’s somewhat related to halloween.
2. The image was too large.