# Screenshot of the Week #104 - Explosions!

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest is over.

*[previous contest](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16943/) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16973/screenshot-of-the-week-105-happy-holidays-2023)*

Hello and welcome to the **104<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [User 23415](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16945/222022)'s picture from [super-mario-odyssey](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-mario-odyssey) won with 14 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](//arqade.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2023-12-04, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2023-12-11, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Explosions

Make something go boom! The bigger, the better! Post a screenshot with bombs, mines, explosives, fireworks, or grenades, but especially their explosions!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](//meta.arqade.com/q/15029).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](//meta.arqade.com/q/14939) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Comment: Debating if next contest should be the Holiday 2023 theme.  It would end on Christmas Day though... so not sure.

Comment: @TimmyJim With this year's Halloween we started on Halloween, so it could be a nice balance :) Or we can prolong the voting period, or have a Screenshot of the Month, but I'm not sure that's necessary..

Comment: My #18 submission was basically an item explosion: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15232/171580

Comment: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15905/screenshot-of-the-week-contest-42-destruction featured quite a few :) @FabianRöling

Comment: Don't have a screenshot, but honorable mention video: https://youtu.be/-c6UNr3M0ok?si=-0W2ueMlrzRJWrnG&t=181

Comment: Can I submit a screenshot of a duck appearing after a bomb is supposed to explode?

Comment: @TheEmptyStringPhotographer Yes, please! There are currently no restrictions on the physics (or logic) behind the explosion :)

Comment: @Joachim I’m asking because of [this](https://regretevator.fandom.com/wiki/Bomb_Defusal) in a Roblox game I often play.

Comment: Perhaps I should have submitted a picture of Boom Boom (from the Mario series)

Comment: @User23415 That's the thing that punches the ground. You mean Bomb-omb.

Comment: No, I mean this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiyDi.jpg. His name is Boom Boom.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant as well. So just for the name? Because it does not explode.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Vegeta final explosion  -  [dragon-ball-z-kakarot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-z-kakarot)

[image: Screnshot]

Comment: Wrap it up boys, we won't find a bigger explosion.... until the next season of Dragon Ball Z

Answer (score 13):

A clutch Explosion in [pokemon-crystal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-crystal)

[image: Pokemon Electrode uses Explosion while paralyzed with 1 Hotpoint remaining]

Comment: For context: this was a fight vs the main rival of the game. I started the turn Paralyzed (**PAR**) with Volty's HP in the yellow (below half). Magneton went first, and managed to land a Thunder (it's a lower accuracy, high damage move). Volty survived with 1 HP remaining, avoided being fully Paralysed this turn (which stops you from performing an action), and its Explosion OHKO'd the Magneton. I won the rest of the battle :)

Comment: Cool guys don't look at explosions. Olds-cool guys can't look at explosions, because they're not rendered.

Comment: @FabianRöling haha, I considered sharing a frame of the Explosion going off, but the animation just adds black spots over the Pokemon sprite (not very visually exciting when there's no animation), and you also lose the contextual info of the HP bar and Paralysis for the 'clutch' moment, so I chose the first frame of the animation instead :)

Comment: Voltymort's sacrifice will never be forgotten.

Answer (score 8):

Tifa being Tifa by dodging rolling away from an explosion in [final-fantasy-7-remake](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-7-remake)

[image]

Comment: Rolling away? Looks more like rolling towards!

Comment: Rolling forward? More like suplexing the explosion

Answer (score 7):

Ifrit in [final-fantasy-8](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-8) on Switch.

[image: Ifrit]

Comment: Thank you @Joachim

Comment: FYI - if you are on Windows, the "Snipping Tool" makes edits like that easy.  Take your original screenshot with the black borders, use the tool, and simply snip away https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jeL1.gif

Answer (score 6):

Young Hugo, understandably indifferent about an English camp being blown to smithereens in [a-plague-tale-innocence](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-plague-tale-innocence)

[image]

Comment: I'll just be the first to say it: [cool guys don't look at explosions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sqz5dbs5zmo).

Comment: @Joachim admin edit powers abused.

Comment: @Fredy31 Yuss! Thanks for that! (Also: no abuse :)

Answer (score 6):

I think I created a galaxy in [dawn-of-war-ii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dawn-of-war-ii).

[image: A screenshot of a doombolt explosion in Dawn of War II]

Context: I was playing a Chaos Sorcerer from the Game Dawn of War II (within the universe of Warhammer 40000). They sometimes have an ability called "doombolt", which allows them to throw magical bolt of energy which blow upon impact. This was taken when the game froze on a frame, when a bolt was blowing.

Comment: There's a cinematic explosion in that game, in which an entire planet is blown apart. But I felt like it was too much of a cliché since everyone already took a screenshot of that. So I felt like posting something more original.

Comment: https://youtu.be/F7iYf-rDrmc?t=68 Gotta admit it looks impressive though

Answer (score 4):

I think I broke it (a flux construct in [zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom))
[image]

Comment: Rules (and giant robots that try to kill you) are meant to be broken.

Answer (score 4):

[image: ~]

```
This Is How It Feels - Stepson
```

---

[Context](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ciV7fDPUoFFkNqTQTy_9ZdfAFvaibSps/view) (video)

---

[need-for-speed-unbound](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-unbound)

Comment: Whoever downvoted this: downvotes don't count for this contest.

Comment: It is really sad to see downvotes here...

Comment: @DiegoBorba Agreed, downvoting is for low quality posts, not posts you disagree with or dislike.