# Screenshot of the Week #105 - Happy Holidays 2023!

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest is over.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16962/screenshot-of-the-week-104-explosions) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16986)*

Hello and welcome to the **105<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Diego Borba](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16967/163757)'s picture from [dragon-ball-z-kakarot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-z-kakarot) won with 14 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](//arqade.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a **two week period**, until 19:00 UTC of 2023-12-25, (the extra week is so this lines up better with the season!) then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2024-01-01, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Christmas/Holiday

As is tradition around this time of year, post a screenshot featuring the holiday season in your game of choice!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](//meta.arqade.com/q/15029).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](//meta.arqade.com/q/14939) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nordberg's midwinter festival in [overlord-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overlord-2)

[image: Nordberg]

Answer (score 10):

A less scary lobby to wait in in [phasmophobia](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phasmophobia)

[image: A less scary lobby to wait in in phasmophobia]

Comment: They took away the spooky jump scare door, so it's not scary at all now :(

Comment: @nightsurfer unsure if there is any other easter egg in the lobby, I'd imagine there is, just havent found it :)

Answer (score 5):

Unexpected tree inside underground base is [sword-of-the-stars-the-pit-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sword-of-the-stars-the-pit-2)

[image]