# Screenshot of the Week #106

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest is over.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16973/screenshot-of-the-week-105-happy-holidays-2023) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16994/screenshot-of-the-week-107-selfie)*

Hello and welcome to the **106<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Daniel Schepler](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16975/87579)'s picture from [overlord-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overlord-2) won with 11 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](//arqade.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2024-01-08, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2024-01-15, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## No theme

There is no theme this week.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](//meta.arqade.com/q/15029).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](//meta.arqade.com/q/14939) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Kratos has been experimenting with flying boat technology in [god-of-war-ragnarok](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/god-of-war-ragnarok).

[image]

Comment: He'll find a way to blame the BOY

Comment: Meanwhile, I'm still waiting for my futuristic flying car... :(

Comment: As someone who doesn't know the game I rather wondered why there is a horned man sticking his head out of the protagonist's bumhole. (Then I noticed the strings, but they could also just be there to make sure he doesn't retract fully into... you know, whatever)

Answer (score 7):

Just vandalizing an ancient tapestry in [baldurs-gate-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baldurs-gate-3)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes it's worth to look at the sky...rim
(sorry)
From [the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim)

[image]

Comment: For a second, I thought that was Rimworld for some reasons

Comment: @Clockwork Skyrimworld?

Answer (score 5):

That was a surprise in [bravely-default-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bravely-default-2)

[image: fairy]

Translation:
What...you are a ... (fairy)?
I was a little bit to early for this shot.

Answer (score 4):

Ignis got turned into a noodle man while duelling with Noctis in [final-fantasy-15](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-15)

[image: A screenshot of a fight between Ignis and Noctis in the Episode Ignis DLC. Ignis looks super thin and with stretchy limbs.]

Context:

> When Noctis uses the Death spell with the Ring of the Lucii, it slowly saps the target's health and the body of the victim is slowly shrinking into nothingness, which is when the target dies instantly. When he used it against Ignis, I had no way to defend myself, so I watched him finish up then used a Phoenix Down. I didn't expect for something like this to happen.

Comment: If you're curious about what it actually looked like before I used a phoenix down: https://steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net/ugc/2292959277862099989/E89E2F9170989CB031A0582F58125E09EFB1BC67/

Comment: noodleman with his pipboy 5000