# Screenshot of the Week #107 - Selfie!

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest is over.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16986/screenshot-of-the-week-106) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17014/screenshot-of-the-week-108)*

Hello and welcome to the **107<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [nightsurfer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16987/87579)'s picture from [god-of-war-ragnarok](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/god-of-war-ragnarok) won with 9 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](//arqade.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2024-01-22, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2024-01-29, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Selfies

Just like in real life: you see something interesting? Let's take a selfie!
Of course the character's face must be visible.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](//meta.arqade.com/q/15029).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](//meta.arqade.com/q/14939) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Comment: When you say "the character's face must be visible", do you mean the character's actual face (as in, anatomically speaking)? Or does it count even if the character is wearing a suit of armour (example: Samus Aran from Metroid)?

Comment: @Clockwork I meant that the character had to be visible from the front, a mask or suit was acceptable

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Kratos is happy to explore Valhalla

[god-of-war-ragnarok](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/god-of-war-ragnarok)

[image]

Comment: _[Hide the Pain Harold intensifies]_

Answer (score 12):

Isaac Clarke, taking a lift in a very dark corridor, in [dead-space](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dead-space)

[image: A very dark screenshot from the 2008 game Dead Space. The only visible lights are the blue hue from Isaac Clarke's helmet, and some distant light from the corridor behind him.]

For comparison sake (i.e. not a second submission), same corridor, but with the light on, since it's difficult to see anything in the dark one:

[image: Same corridor as in the previous screenshot, but this time the light is working, so we can clearly see the details of the walls and the character's armor.]

Comment: A bit darker, please, I can still see three lines!

Comment: BTW, when I increase my screen gamma, I can see that this does not even qualify, the theme is "selfie".

Comment: @FabianRöling It doesn't? I took a screenshot of Isaac Clarke's face (wearing the helmet) as the lift was advancing towards the camera. Let me know if I should retake a brighter version of the screenshot to make it more clear (pun intended).

Comment: Oh, now that you say it, I can just about figure out where a person is supposed to be. But yes, a brighter version would be way better. I do not know if you are still allowed to edit your existing post.

Comment: @FabianRöling I probably will post a comment, or a second link below the original image. The very dark one is still my submission

Comment: Someone downvoted this... Why?

Comment: @User23415 I'm thinking it might have been related to what we discussed with Fabian Rölling, since it was unclear the screenshot did contain a person.

Comment: @Clockwork But downvotes aren't counted for the purpose of determining the winner.

Comment: I actually like the dark version, but I think it would work better if it were cropped into a square so the pixels that aren't `#000000` take up more of the screen

Comment: I think people even slightly familiar with the game recognized the three stripes immediately. I also believe that was the strength of the original/actual entry (still, thanks for the effort for providing a clearer alternative :).

Comment: Doesn't matter, I still prefer the dark one

Comment: Dude, you need to up your gamma.

Comment: @Neonit For context, that corridor is supposed to be that dark. The first time you arrive, the light is on, but the second time, the light is out. I took a screenshot of when it was dark because I thought it would make a nice wallpaper

Answer (score 5):

Death Mountain (from [zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom)) at night can be stunning.

[image]

Comment: Are there any rules to posting the same picture twice? [Contest 93](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16799/124566)

Comment: @Wondercricket good catch! I don't know, we should ask to the creator of the contest

Comment: Well, we don't seem to actually have this written down in the "rules" anywhere for Screenshot of the Week.  I would say so long as the screenshot didn't win a previous contest, I am fine with it.

Comment: @TimmyJim That sounds good to me! I don't think it's ever happened before, so thought I'd inquire. Might be good to add to the rules for future contests? "If you have a screenshot that you submitted in a previous contest, but did not win, you are allowed to re-use in" (or something like that)

Comment: @Wondercricket Perhaps this may be enough: "Resubmissions are allowed, but screenshots that have won previous contests are not eligible to win again."

Comment: I took a much better screenshot, can I change my entry?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't change entries after the first vote is cast, and definitely not after general submissions have been closed. Maybe the new screenshot will work for next week?