# Screenshot of the Week #108

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest is over.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16994/screenshot-of-the-week-107-selfie) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17026/screenshot-of-the-week-109-glitches-and-bugs)*

Hello and welcome to the **108<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [arghtype](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16998/163757)'s picture from [god-of-war-ragnarok](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/god-of-war-ragnarok) won with 13 upvotes! Two weeks in a row a submission from God of War: Ragnarok won!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](//arqade.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2024-02-05, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2024-02-12, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## No Theme

There is no theme this week.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](//meta.arqade.com/q/15029).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](//meta.arqade.com/q/14939) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Comment: Glad you posted, I just realized it was time to close the old one

Comment: Don’t want to start a long discussion here, but why do we tag “screenshots-of-the-week” posts with the “discussion” tag?

Comment: @arghtype Because all meta posts need 1 of 4 tags: [meta-tag:discussion], [meta-tag:support], [meta-tag:bug] or [meta-tag:feature-request]. It won't even allow the question to post without one of those tags. and discussion is the most appropriate of those 4.

Comment: Yep. [discussion] is pretty much the catch-all. I would love it if [tag:community-event] was promoted to be a 5th pillar of meta question type, but that's unlikely to happen as it would be a network-wide change

Comment: No [problems uploading images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396425/cant-upload-images), then? That's good news! (These first ones were still on Imgur, I see.)

Answer (score 13):

Fortress monastery "Martyr" is about to make a warp jump in [warhammer-40k-inquisitor-martyr](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warhammer-40k-inquisitor-martyr)

[image]

Comment: I can't unhear this sound from DOW II https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jW9BPyXkPmM

Answer (score 10):

[snowrunner](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/snowrunner)

[image: a Scout truck shining its headlights down a steep trail]

Answer (score 8):

The weird and moody world of [babbdi](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/babbdi):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Preparation for dinner [dragon-quest-11-s](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-quest-11-s)

[image: dinner]

Comment: Oh look, it's "[King Kaliente](https://www.mariowiki.com/King_Kaliente)" from Super Mario Galaxy 2!

Answer (score 5):

Bowser's [haiku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haiku) in [super-mario-rpg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-mario-rpg)

[image: Bowser delivering a haiku in the game Super Mario RPG on SNES, as Mario silently watches.]

> Like the moon over
> the day, my genius and brawn
> are lost on these fools. ~Haiku

Answer (score 3):

You know someone in [trails-of-cold-steel-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trails-of-cold-steel-3) has got their plot armor on when they stop receiving damage before you can finish them off

[image: Campanella's Plot Armor in Trails of Cold Steel 3]

Comment: It reminds me of games in which I overleveled to the point I could roll over most of the early bosses, only to realise all the fights are scripted to be lost... :(

Comment: This battles you have to loose in order to proceed. And you waste rare item's; because you do not know. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

[palworld](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/palworld) *Feeding time! NOOOOOOO!!!*

[image: Feeding time! NOOOOOOO!!!]

Comment: [Related Meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17007/124566) ;)