# Screenshot of the Week #109: Glitches and Bugs

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest is over.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17014/screenshot-of-the-week-108) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17035/screenshot-of-the-week-110)*

Hello and welcome to the **109<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [arghtype](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17024/163757)'s picture from [warhammer-40k-inquisitor-martyr](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warhammer-40k-inquisitor-martyr) won with 12 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](//arqade.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2024-02-19, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2024-02-26, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Glitches and Bugs

Post a screenshot showing some funny bug or glitch you encountered!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](//meta.arqade.com/q/15029).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](//meta.arqade.com/q/14939) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Answer (score 13):

The famous Nosepiper of Ard Skellig in [the-witcher-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-witcher-3):

[image]

Comment: This guy is [quite buggy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09EFm.jpg).

Comment: This guy gives me nightmares.

Comment: @pinckerman You make me glad I haven't posted my melty face from a game I've been playing forever.

Comment: @Clockwork Now I'm intrigued - if we warn pinckerman not to visit this SotW edition anymore, will you post it? :D

Comment: @Joachim Eh, maybe I'll post 2 of them for the 2 next screenshots of the week? 

Comment: @Joachim so thoughtful :D

Answer (score 9):

Madeline rebels against the sign AND physics in the recently released [Celeste64](https://maddymakesgamesinc.itch.io/celeste64)

[image: "Secret sign, do not read" behind a wall]

This game was made in about a week by the team behind [celeste](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/celeste), which is inspired by Mario64 in textures, music and camera terribleness. ;) But the level design is much better, it was a lot of fun to play through! That takes something between 2 and 8 hours, depending on prior Celeste and 3D game experience.

Comment: Never heard of this version, thanks!

Comment: wow this game has even a linux port.

Comment: Yep, that is where the screenshot comes from!

Comment: Is this a bug, or an easter egg? (not being a stickler - just curious)

Comment: It is a bug. You are supposed to break the wall with a dash, but the same button reads signs.

Answer (score 8):

When you only wear the stealth helmet.

[starfield](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starfield)

[image: Starfield helmet glitch]

Comment: Can't get headshotted if you don't got a head

Comment: @TimmyJim Well, depends on the gender

Comment: ..must be a Bethesda game..

Answer (score 6):

When you think that Pokemon Violet takes place in Paldea, but it's actually Pandora [pokemon-scarlet-violet](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-scarlet-violet)

[image: Pokemon bug]

Comment: It's unfortunate that these kind of bugs appear more often then they should in SV...

Comment: @Wondercricket there were several of these situations... but nothing game-breaking, luckily

Answer (score 4):

A guard is patrolling around the casino in [payday-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/payday-2). Except his legs are stuck in the dirt.

[image: A guard patrolling around the bank, but the game glitched and he appears to be half inside the ground.]

Comment: A heisters dream.  A guard unable to move :)

Answer (score 3):

"Your equipment will now be returned to you" - Shrine of Light in [zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom)
[image]
Last time I saw my stuff, it was *visible*...

Comment: I'm seeing a McDonald's sign in the back