# Screenshot of the Week #110

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest is over.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17026/screenshot-of-the-week-109-glitches-and-bugs-submissions-closed-vote-now) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17045/screenshot-of-the-week-111)*

Hello and welcome to the **110<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Joachim's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17031/163757)'s picture from [the-witcher-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-witcher-3) won with 13 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](//arqade.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2024-03-04, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2024-03-11, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## No Theme

There is no theme this week.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](//meta.arqade.com/q/15029).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](//meta.arqade.com/q/14939) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's sit down and have a cup of tea in this eerie room's corner. [fallout-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fallout-4)

[image: a calm corner]

Comment: And let's admire these abstract paintings of traces of chipped paint on pieces of plywood (for some reason) [which is actually something I could have made and might make].

Answer (score 11):

I believe it's time for another [a-plague-tale-innocence](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-plague-tale-innocence) (and vertical) screenshot:

[image]

Comment: At least It looks so much better than vertical pictures with a phone

Comment: @Clockwork Than horizontal ones, you mean?

Comment: I was trying to make a not-so-funny joke about the fact some people (myself included) don't enjoy vertically recorded videos

Comment: @Clockwork Oh, right, me neither. But these vertical images look lovely in the widget on the main site, like for example [this one](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16596/222022) did :)

Comment: Soo you have a super wide screen pivoted 90 degrees?

Comment: @Neonit It's my preferred way of playing. And after a few hours, the real world starts to look ridiculous.

Answer (score 4):

A little rest before I hunt more metal slimes. [dragon-quest-8](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-quest-8)

[image: rest]

Comment: Meh no good hunt.

Answer (score 4):

*Embrace loss*, Mother Superior.  [baldurs-gate-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baldurs-gate-3)

> [image]

Comment: Sorry to obscure your contribution, but that was spoilerish for me, and might be for others :|

Answer (score 4):

[armored-core-vi-fires-of-rubicon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/armored-core-vi-fires-of-rubicon)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Something went wrong with the Farseer's face in [dawn-of-war-ii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dawn-of-war-ii).

[image: A screenshot of the game Dawn of War II, except the camera is focusing on a very creepy looking Farseer. The body is bizarrely deformed, and the face is scarily stretched.]

Comment: I think one glitchy screenshot will be enough.

Comment: Is this the melty face [you mentioned](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17026/screenshot-of-the-week-109-glitches-and-bugs#comment49818_17031)?

Comment: @Joachim Yeah, that's one among some screenshots of very weird things going on with this character that happened during the game. In one occurrence, the character fell to the ground but the face remained where it was, resulting in a stretchy messy flesh from the floating face to the ground.

Comment: Oh well, nightmares, here we go again.

Comment: I'm going to post [this nightmare material](https://steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net/ugc/820128333702755712/76AE94719EEADBB5AB95683F9E3D8CB8AB60C1E7/?imw=5000&imh=5000&ima=fit&impolicy=Letterbox&imcolor=%23000000&letterbox=false) as a comment because I don't intend to submit another one of these.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
Ow. Lynels hit hard in [zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom)

Comment: This is a Screen No Gamer want to See in a Game. 

Answer (score 1):

For International Womens Day (Mar 8), Senua. from [hellblade-senuas-sacrifice](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hellblade-senuas-sacrifice)

[image: Senua]

Comment: I think submission was closed 2 days ago