# Screenshot of the Week #71!

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This Contest has Ended.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16484) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16508)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **71<sup>st</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Neonit's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16490/8350) picture from [the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim) won with 13 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2022-08-15, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2022-08-22, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## No Theme

There's no theme this week, so just send us the best you've got!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Comment: Thank zeus  for @Joachim picking up all the mod slack on Arqade, heh.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Assassin's Creed Odyssey (SOW-71)]

---

[assassins-creed-odyssey](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-odyssey)

Answer (score 11):

Silvercoat Ethel being awesome in [xenoblade-chronicles-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xenoblade-chronicles-3)

[image]

Comment: It's so beautiful

Answer (score 10):

[image: Bowser's Fury Cats]

Cat's love Mario in [bowsers-fury](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bowsers-fury) (and yes, the Switch does vibrate when they do this)

Comment: So sweet. I am melting.

Answer (score 8):

Visiting the Void in [dishonored-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dishonored-2).

[image]

Comment: Is this intended? It looks very bugged. But also cool!

Comment: @FabianRöling It should be as intended. The Void is depicted as an empty space where physics-defying configurations of a kind of spikey mineral- or stone-like element are combined or at times merged with objects of importance you can find in the in-game real world.

Comment: This place scares me.

Comment: Magnificent, @Joachim...

Answer (score 6):

pep power aboria's blessing in [dragon-quest-xi](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-quest-xi)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

These poor Brotherhood Paladins died to a Raider, but at least they died together.

[fallout-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fallout-3)

[image]

Comment: I'm thinking they weren't in their underwear when they died, though, and you helped them a bit in that regard.... ;)

Comment: I've honestly been annoyed with carry weight, so I just modav'd my carry weight to 1250. As such, I just open inventories and Take All with A. Did that too quick before I realized these fellas were holding hands :')

Answer (score 5):

[image]

The yao guai (mutated black bear) is not impressed by my trespassing on his domain in [fallout-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fallout-4).

(Actually this particular yao guai is bugged, no idea what's up with him. But I guess that's the only way to get a good photo of a rabid rage monster...)

Comment: Maybe it got convinced that there is no nuclear war in Boston when it visited lake Yaoguai.

Comment: Or something. He just stands there and ignores me, and my attacks don't have any effect even though he does show up in VATS. Probably the most benign "immortal enemy" bug I've found on FO4 yet.

Comment: (S)he looks very surprised. (S)he also seems to have misplaced their cover when trying to peek around it.

Comment: @FabianRöling godly references only

Comment: @nightsurfer I'm so happy that someone got it! :D

Answer (score 3):

[image: Capt. Unionhawk sits at the end of the bowsprit as a Shiba called Admiral Dog floats above the sea]

This is why I'm just the Captain of The Lonliest Number and he's an Admiral in [sea-of-thieves](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sea-of-thieves).

Answer (score 2):

Still Life in [fall-guys-ultimate-knockout](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fall-guys-ultimate-knockout)

(I got disconnected and everyone else started floating in place)

[image: Bean guys jumping and racing along Big Fans]