# Screenshot of the Week #72 - Living with Nature

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This Contest has Ended.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16495) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16516)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **72<sup>nd</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Faither's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16497/222022) picture from [assassins-creed-odyssey](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-odyssey) won with 12 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2022-08-29, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2022-09-05, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Living with Nature

Befitting last week's winner, the current Screenshot of the Week's theme is 'Living with Nature'.
Post screenshots of your character working with nature/the environment, from buildings to befriending animals to using nature to defeat your foe.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Comment: Thanks again honorary moderator!

Comment: Very fitting, because a Minecraft YouTuber/streamer I watch for a long time has recently created an "Outdoors" channel! But that's for real nature, not simulated, ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finding respite and time to mourn in some overgrown castle ruins in [a-plague-tale-innocence](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-plague-tale-innocence).

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Someone surely was once living with nature here on this island in [subnautica](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subnautica).

[image: island ruins]

Comment: Interesting you chose one of the few land locations in an otherwise aquatic game :)

Comment: I have tried to create an underwater photo that suits my aspiration, but I failed to do so while trying to keep the spoiler impact low. It is totally possible that I just couldn't find the right locations or perspectives. But as I started to take pictures of Subnautica, I noticed an enormous difference between the beauty of the environment perceived while playing and what was reflected by the image. My theory is that Subnautica reaches a high level of perceived beauty, less through graphics, but rather the overall combination of different features (visuals, audio, atmosphere).

Comment: Also, I didn't feel random creature photos would fit the theme as good. I had no idea how to show the *character working with one of the creatures* in Subnautica. Maybe with heavy spoilers. So I went for buildings and flora.

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes, nature is scary.  [animal-crossing-new-horizons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal-crossing-new-horizons)

[image]

Comment: I love the chaotic energy this shot has

Answer (score 4):

An angry alpha Bidoof in [pokemon-legends-arceus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-legends-arceus)

[image: alpha bidoof]