# Screenshot of the Week #73

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16508) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16529)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **73<sup>rd</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the [winner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/431GD.jpg) of the previous contest! [Joachim's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16510/222022) picture from [a-plague-tale-innocence](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-plague-tale-innocence) won with 13 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2022-09-12, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2022-09-19, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## No Theme

There's no theme this week, so just send us the best you've got!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Comment: So many good shots this week!

Comment: What is going to happen, if there are three or more shots with the same score?

Comment: @Neonit They'll simply share the first place I believe. But it has no precedent, so maybe we'll need a new rule (like wait until the first new vote changes the situation?).

Comment: Well, not for three winners, but definitely for two: [#50](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16136/171580), [#52](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16160/171580) and [#61](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16320/171580)

Comment: @FabianRöling Yeah, exactly. In those cases the first place was shared (there was a fourth tie that was 'solved' in a different way).

Comment: We need a runoff (I hope leo.org translate it correct)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

---

[mirrors-edge-catalyst](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mirrors-edge-catalyst)

Comment: I voted for this one, because my favourite YouTuber and steamer was the "technical design director" for this game. :D https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4ZS2guXqa_gQOEP45h86pg5PE8pR16nq (It also looks nice.)

Comment: Man this was a great game

Comment: @Faither Thanks for your screenshot!  This actually got me to play Catalyst just over the weekend after playing the original but never touching the sequel. Very fun game! Too bad the story sucked

Comment: @childe What got me to play this game was one of my favorite bands (CHVRCHES) cameoed in the game with their song Warning Call

Answer (score 8):

[image]

[tinykin](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tinykin) happily flying off to explode

Answer (score 8):

Remember corona?

[image]

---

[dishonored-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dishonored-2)

Comment: Sigh how could we forget 

Answer (score 7):

Nothing special but so sweet. Best buddies slimeknight and his slime.
[dragon-quest-x11](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-quest-x11)

[image: buddy]

Answer (score 7):

Trevor coming *back to life*.

[image]

[grand-theft-auto-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-5)

Answer (score 3):

My friends and I are welcoming [dark-souls-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-souls-3) multiplayer back with the usual shenanigans.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Homura Patting in Atelier Shallie]

Homura complimenting Miruca in [atelier-shallie](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atelier-shallie) with Head Pats