# Screenshot of the Week Contest #54: Happy Holidays 2021!

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest is over.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16160) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16183)*

---

Hello and welcome to the 54<sup>th</sup> edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [arghtype's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16162/28182) evening ride in [days-gone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/days-gone), won with a handy 16 votes:

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2021-12-21, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2021-12-28, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Theme

The season-appropriate theme for this week is **Christmas** or more broadly, **Holidays**. We're looking for whatever the festive-holiday season means to you: family, friends, fun hats or decorations, give us the best seasonal content you have!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Comment: Bunny in snow: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14919/171580

Comment: Joke too long for comment: https://pastebin.com/YdvJ17mn

Comment: @FabianRöling your link is private, so it doesn't help!

Comment: @TimmyJim No, it's not, but the text actually says: "this is a private paste or is pending moderation", so I guess they found my number spam suspicious. :D What I had posted there was "No, it's not holidays [\*]. ;) (r/unexpectedfactorial)", where [\*] is 2021!, meaning the factorial of 2021. It's 5805 digits long. :D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's the holiday season in [new-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-world).  The tree is up in Everfall:

[image]

Comment: It looks even better now that the event has progressed some https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8k3f.jpg

Answer (score 12):

Wishing you a Corrado Christmas! [forza-horizon-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forza-horizon-5)

[image]

Answer (score 11):

[image]

Merry Christmas, from [dungeon-defenders-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeon-defenders-2)

Answer (score 9):

[image]

big hatz everybody

Comment: [Undeleted] - You were 4 minutes late. I'll let it pass :P. It's Christmas!

Comment: Thank you! It was really fun to make this! :]

Answer (score 7):

[final-fantasy-xiv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-xiv) The Saint of Nymeia as two new helpers this year (Myself and Rudy)

[image: Rudy delivering gifts in Final Fantasy XIV]

Answer (score 6):

Not quite christmas but closer to new year, a Japanese festival at a shrine. Although someone is perhaps little bit too focused on the task at hand to relax... [grisaia-no-kajitsu](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grisaia-no-kajitsu)

[image: Makina is focused]

Answer (score 6):

[phasmophobia](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phasmophobia) has our ghost hunters getting a little festive!

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if Christmas apparel makes it less or more creepy.

Comment: My group and I have played for long enough that it's just a puzzle game at this point. It's only scary when a ghost event occurs and it pretends to hunt or breaths in your ear ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just a normal happy family (Binding of Isaac Repentance)

[image: A normal happy family]