# Screenshot of the Week Contest #55

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16171) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16210)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **55<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Timmy Jim's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16177/8350) celebrating the holiday season in [new-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-world) won with 14 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2022-01-03, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2022-01-10, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## No Theme

No theme this week, post your best (or worst) screenshots!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Comment: I really wanted that [Forza submission](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16174/163757) to win last week's. :(

Comment: The Forza submission really was nice (and from a relatively new contributor, also).

Comment: @Wipqozn Please mark [the winner](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16187/171580) as accepted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I loved [a-plague-tale-innocence](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-plague-tale-innocence), especially its late medieval European setting and plot, but this moment when your young brother 'stumbles' upon a body-strewn battlefield was probably the most impressive:

[image]

Comment: Wow, that is incredibly detailed world. Will definitely check it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I can't play [forza-horizon-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forza-horizon-5) without pausing every five minutes and taking dozens of screenshots of the stunningly beautiful visuals and sceneries

[image: Yellow Car on Bridge facing Rainforest in game Forza Horizon 5]

It's so hard to just pick 1 screenshot when I have dozens other that are equally as gorgeous.

While the picture above is taken using the in-game Photo Mode, the real-time gameplay visuals look almost identical.

The screenshot was printscreened from a cloud streaming of the game being played on Xbox Series X in Performance mode. Read my comment below for more details.

Comment: "Read my comment below for more details." Uh ... Which comment?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel strange, maybe it got removed? To re-iterate: "I'm subscribed to **xCloud** (Xbox's cloud streaming service) which lets me play *all* 1st party Xbox games (+100 more games) from anywhere, including on the cloud from a browser, bc I can't afford an Xbox Series S|X rn. While it requires Ethernet cable for a stable connection and low input lag, it's incredible how I can play Forza Horizon 5 on the highest quality, Halo Infinite, and other games I never thought I'd try. I highly recommend it to anyone with a decent internet and ability to pay ~$10/mo (first month is $1 for new subs)"

Comment: That was probably removed because it 200% sounds like spam. It really does.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel trust me, I know it does. I sound like a huuge Xbox shill, don't I? But it's so extremely difficult to talk honestly about how great xCloud (and Game Pass) is without coming off as a glaringly obvious paid Microsoft employee :/ Still, I hope you'll take the comment in good faith 

Comment: Trust me, I know how good it is. Plenty of people do. I know you want to share that information for others that want to play but can't. However, there's better places to share that information. Unfortunately, I don't think that this is the correct place to share it. Just the "I'm using .... to play the game" should be enough, like how you have in your post, in my opinion. But, I'm not a moderator, so, my words have the same value as the paper they are written on.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel No, I appreciate your input :) What your saying makes sense and my wall of comment only litters the purpose of this contest -- to highlight great screenshots. As someone who's tasted the pudding himself/herself, you probably understand my desire to recommend this service whenever I can 

Comment: in some threads comments are fine for leaving opinions, especially when they relate to the topic of the SE. I believe SotW is one of those threads, since it's meant to be fun. If I tell you what a great game - I don't know - Portal 2 or The Witcher 3 is, no one in their right mind would delete that comment mistaking it for spam. Your initial comment was probably seen isolated in a queue and flagged.

Answer (score 8):

[demons-souls](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/demons-souls) remake is beautiful. And players' messages are on point as always.

[image: a little falling down never hurt anyone]

Answer (score 6):

With the new Matrix movie, [dungeon-defenders-awakened](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeon-defenders-awakened) reminds us who really is "the one"

[image: Rubber Duckie, you're the one]

Answer (score 5):

Just Tuesday... [mugen](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mugen)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

At the end of Act XI: The Atheneum - Chapter 8, in [blade-and-soul](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blade-and-soul), you can just climb the walls around, and see the cool portals from a lot closer.

The developers forgot to mark that wall as not climbable.

[image: me, on top of wall, watching a cool portal]

Answer (score 4):

All barriers dispersed! [zelda-ocarina-of-time](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-ocarina-of-time)

[image]

Comment: I'm getting flashbacks from doing these on Master Quest mode

Comment: The Master Quest mode where the whole game is a mirror image of the original? I've tried watching speedruns, and... is is hard just watching those guys work.

Comment: I think the version with the mirrored world was the remaster for the 3DS. Master Quest was a version that was released on the GameCube with the dungeons being much more difficult

Answer (score 4):

[final-fantasy-xiv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-xiv) Just a few seconds/minutes/hours more...
[image]

Comment: [Your hope has become despair!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h1Z1o-_DHJE)

Comment: @Wipqozn "Epic villain laugh" or someone imitating an old malfunctioning motorcycle?

Comment: @Joachim Por que no los dos?

Comment: @Wipqozn Bien, gracias. Y tú?

Answer (score 4):

My first one:

[image]

Screenshot is from [trails-of-cold-steel-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trails-of-cold-steel-4)

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! It's a pretty nice screenshot, but you can provide which game this is from?

Comment: trails of cold steel 4 I wrote it in the image.

Comment: Ah ha, thanks I see that now :)