# Screenshot of the Week #56 - Sweet Rides

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16183) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16229)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **56<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Joachim's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16187/163757) screenshot standing among a battlefield in [a-plague-tale-innocence](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-plague-tale-innocence) won with 13 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2022-01-17, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2022-01-24, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Sweet Rides

Show off your vehicles (or *a vehicle*) in your favorite game! It could be a car, truck, plane, boat, or whatever vehicle transports you around!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[returnal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/returnal)

This is Helios. It was a nice ship, until I crash-landed on this damn planet. But then I crashed on it again. And again.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I'm surprised no one has posted anything from **[forza-horizon-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forza-horizon-5)** yet.

Lamborghini Sesto Elemento:

[image: Forza Horizon 5: Lamborghini Sesto Elemento screenshot]

This screenshot was taken while using the in-game Photo mode, which is almost identical to the real-time gameplay graphics, but allows for some light post-processing effects (focus, color correction, exposure, aperture, etc.).

Comment: I was expecting someone to also post a picture from this game!

Comment: There are a bunch of photorealistic racing games that could make good screenshots for this competition.

Comment: I have not even bought the game yet and I'm hearing my graphics card melting.

Comment: @Fredy31: I have been cloud streaming the game via Xbox Game Pass (costs like $10/mo), and that screenshot above is literally taken from my browser. If you have a decent internet connection, get yourself Game Pass + Ethernet cable for cheap access to FH5 with high graphic fidelity :)

Answer (score 8):

We all know who is gonna win this...
Bone Wagon (and Glottis) from [grim-fandango](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grim-fandango)

[image]

Comment: Since this now actually does have the most votes (together with another submission): Why? Is this game particularly popular or so? I've never heard of it.

Comment: @FabianRöling it's the first 3dimensional LucasArts graphic adventure, a little masterpiece from Tim Schafer winner of several awards in 1998.

Comment: Here is a video clip of where the screenshot comes from: https://youtu.be/jb6H9LRZAUg?t=326 
and of course there is `What a relief. I was getting concerned that our transportation wasn't ostentatious enough.` https://youtu.be/jb6H9LRZAUg?t=633 
and here is a 2 minute clip of the `Best of Glottis` https://youtu.be/-41bQMoR0Uk 
... hilarious

Answer (score 7):

Just floating down the flooded city of Seattle in [the-last-of-us-part-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-last-of-us-part-2)

[image: Ellie in a goats]

Answer (score 7):

New crime added to rap sheet: operating a forklift without proper certification in [payday-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/payday-2).

[image: Chains driving the forklift in Meltdown]

Comment: that's an OSHA violation.

Comment: It's a good thing I have been pardoned by 16th President of the United States, Abraham Lincoln.

Comment:  come with me and you'll be in a world of osha violations 

Answer (score 7):

[image: SDS Fenrir in Final Fantasy XIV]

Taking a ride though the Coerthas Central Highlands in [final-fantasy-xiv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-xiv) on the SDS Fenrir

Comment: Beautiful looking ride. It probably costs a lot to buy?

Comment: @LoreFriendly [only 23.99€](https://store.finalfantasyxiv.com/ffxivstore/en-gb/product/483) making it the most expensive 1-player mount on the store

Answer (score 6):

[forza-horizon-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forza-horizon-5)

Is that a **SUPRA**?!

[image]

Answer (score 5):

falcie crashes my plane

[image]

[final-fantasy-xiii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-xiii)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not one personally to ride with a biker gang, but I could change my mind if I were an [overwatch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overwatch) character.

[image: Overwatch Route 66]

Answer (score 5):

Everyone on the shark, we're going mining!
[image: People riding a flying shark balloon]
The shark is a modded vehicle addition for [7-days-to-die](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7-days-to-die).

Comment: You sure your game didnt... Jump the shark?

Answer (score 5):

My Hummingbird MKII, a jet-powered VTOL short-range exploration vehicle in [kerbal-space-program](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kerbal-space-program)

[image]

Comment: Submissions are closed! But we'll allow it ;)