# Screenshot of the Week #57

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This competition has ended.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16210) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16245)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **57<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [arghtype's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16212/8350) picture of Helios from [returnal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/returnal) won with 12 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2022-01-31, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2022-02-07, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## No Theme

No theme this week, post your best (or worst) screenshots!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Comment: Please mark [the winner](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16230/171580) as accepted.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[manifold-garden](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manifold-garden) has me feeling like a 4D creature trying to live in a 3D world.

[image: colors]

Answer (score 13):

End of my [journey](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/journey)                                        [image]

Answer (score 11):

[wordle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordle) is being incredibly mean to me (although this is actually the [absurdle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/absurdle) variant)

[image]

Comment: Is this like "Mastermind", but with words? The colours and the layout remind me of it, but then the first guesses would be unusual.

Comment: @FabianRöling basically, although absurdle is an adversarial variant, so early guesses do end up looking strange

Comment: Shouldn't you guess as many distinct letters as possible then?

Comment: @FabianRöling That's working under the assumption that I'm good at this. Also, your guesses have to be valid words themselves.

Comment: Ah, that explains why you don't just start with "ABCDE".

Comment: @FabianRöling if you want to give a try to the normal version, its free! https://www.powerlanguage.co.uk/wordle/ And then you can come brag about your score in the chatroom. We are lots of players of wordle lol

Comment: It just got bought by NYT.

Answer (score 10):

Still slowly playing through [the-long-dark](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-long-dark), had a nice opportunity for hunting in Broken Railroad this morning :)

[image: hunting]

Answer (score 7):

The most aesthetically pleasing lighting for the most disgusting shower in [7-days-to-die](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7-days-to-die)

[image]

Comment: Is this with any kind of mods or anything? It looks graphically better than I remember, though it has been a bit since I played.

Comment: @TimmyJim It's bone stock vanilla! I run games at 60fps though, so I can usually up the graphical quality a lot without sacrificing frames.

Comment: What is this, a shower for ants?

Comment: The most recent alpha patch had a lot of graphical and QOL improvements to the game

Answer (score 7):

[it-takes-two](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/it-takes-two) to explore space!

[image]

Answer (score 5):

One of my endless screenshots from **[forza-horizon-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forza-horizon-5)**, because the game is so darn beautiful:

[image: Forza Horizon 5]

<sup>Screenshot taken from in-browser with the game running via cloud streaming, so it's compressed, yet looks pretty good.</sup>

While the photo above is taken using the game's in-game Photo mode, the real-time graphics are near identical!

Comment: Could you get rid of the advertisement? It sounds like Microsoft hired you to post this.

Comment: @BoogaRoo: it's really hard to talk about Xbox Game Pass without coming off as a shill -- the service is just that good :/ I've edited some of the text to better highlight my point (cloud streaming => compressed visuals).

Answer (score 4):

Just me, casually swimming on land, in [blade-and-soul](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blade-and-soul) UE4.

[image: me, swimming on land]

It's hard to see, since it isn't animated.

List of bugs happening at the same time:

- I'm in a state which says that I'm always walking;
- I tried to do an attack underwater (previous state lets you do that) and was placed on top of the water;
- The floor geometry failed to let the camera go above, where it should be;
- The light failed to transition between areas on this spot;
- I'm swimming somewhere that has no water underneath.

This is the type of broken stuff that [blade-and-soul](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blade-and-soul) UE4 brought to us :(