# Screenshot of the Week #58 - Pets

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This competition has ended

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16229) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16262)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **58<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Batophobia's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16230/163757) picture from [manifold-garden](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manifold-garden) won with 16 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2022-02-14, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2022-02-21, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Pets

Submit your virtual pets that join you by your side in your gaming adventures!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Comment: Past entry: [Undead dogs](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15139/171580)

Comment: Who will be the first to submit an Arceus screenshot? The race is on!

Comment: @GammaGames I had to.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is my good boy Eneru from [pokemon-legends-arceus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-legends-arceus)

[image]

<sup>(The only one in my team that looks like an actual pet)</sup>

Comment: Woah there I do have a Japanese-Style dragon as a pet at home! It even can do hyperbeam! Whats that dragons are not real pets?

Comment: @Fredy31 if it sits, I submits.

Comment: Such a good kitty

Answer (score 13):

Setting sail with a scaly crew in [ark-survival-evolved](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ark-survival-evolved).
[image: Raft on the water with an ankylosaurus and an allosaurus on board.]

Comment: This thing broke my brain. That is taller than the sail mast. I imagine must be a lot of fun sailing that. :-D

Answer (score 12):

My Lizard Doggo from [satisfactory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/satisfactory)

[image: doggo]

Answer (score 9):

I know not exactly a pet, but I really like the two. [jak-and-daxter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jak-and-daxter)

[image: jak and daxter]

Comment: I miss this game series.

Comment: Its jak and daxter series

Comment: Oh I know! It's just been years since I played them.  Well over 10 (maybe closer to 15) years.  I loved the second game.

Comment: jak and dexter was my 1. game I played on PS2. In german it was released at 2001.

Comment: I really enjoyed the first, but never really got into the second. Haven't played the 3rd

Answer (score 8):

[image: Surveying]

Me and my pets Fran, Nightingale and Eos surveying the foggy abyss of the Nymian Ruins in Outer La Noscea of [final-fantasy-xiv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-xiv)

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if this can be considered a pet - it's unlikely it would consider itself a pet - but the **Cheshire Cat** from [american-mcgees-alice-in-wonderland](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/american-mcgees-alice-in-wonderland) (that is the 2000 version, explicitly) is such a friggin' great character: wonderful design, expressions (both physically and verbally), and an awesome voice (by Roger L. Jackson):

[image]

Comment: I get some bad vibes from this kitty...

Answer (score 4):

Dont care if it DQs me because they are not pixels and their names are not even Video Games related, you will be shown my kitties.

[image]

So we got Milky, the brown one (feisty af), we got Zen (short for Zenitsu) the black and white one, as stupid as the character he's named after, and the black one is Ajax, and god is he a sleepy kitty.

Comment: Had the same feeling to post my own cat, but I gave up.

Comment: lol. Mostly wanted to put at least something because the SOTW was a day old and no entrants. Difficult theme i guess.

Comment: Now if you had taken a photo of this photo on your monitor, I think it would still technically fit the requirements :) Anyway, real cats +1.

Comment: smh it's just a friendly contest and people are downvoting, yikes

Comment: Dont mind, shown my kitties to the world. Its all in good fun. And really, I think I can give myself the badge of honor of getting the first downvote of the contest.

Comment: @nightsurfer - we don't consider downvotes when we tally scores, so at the end of the day it doesn't affect much.