# Screenshot of the Week #59

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## Submissions are closed

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16245) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16285)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **59<sup>th</sup>** edition of Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [pinckerman's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16247/28182) picture of a good boy named Eneru from [pokemon-legends-arceus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-legends-arceus) won with 16 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2022-03-01, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2022-03-08, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## No Theme

No theme this week, post your best (or worst) screenshots!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image: Linca in Atelier Escha and Logy]

Linca is about to destroy something in [atelier-escha-and-logy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atelier-escha-and-logy)

Answer (score 11):

Ah, [cyberpunk-2077](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cyberpunk-2077) ... please never change...

I'm sure that that's not how you drink coffee...

And yes, this is with the 1.5 update.

[image: Floating coffee cup in front of "Detective Ward"]

Comment: And the person in the back is… shaving? Holding liquid without a cup? Getting an electric shock?

Comment: @FabianRöling I actually have no idea... But since I enabled AMD FSR, it can be anything...

Comment: Man, are there still many issues with this game? Yea this one probably isn't game breaking, but come onnnnnnnnnnn.

Comment: @TimmyJim Yes, there's still lots of small bugs that existed since release. But besides that, you can actually feel the improvements. It's a bit harder to find jank, but you will find it.

Answer (score 8):

"Nothing bad will happen... right?"

Observing an elderly man on a rather dangerous walk in [just-cause-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/just-cause-3)

[image: Elderly gentleman having a walk]

Answer (score 8):

Absolute chad on my Ironman account on [oldschool-runescape](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oldschool-runescape)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Link is about to destroy something in [zelda-ocarina-of-time](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-ocarina-of-time)

Comment: The nostalgia on this one is great

Answer (score 6):

i will free us [ico](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ico)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I stepped away for a minute to grab some water, and came back to this...

[image]

Thanks [control](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/control)

Comment: "Hey. Are you out there? Could you please continue playing? We're getting bored."

Comment: ♫ He's lost control again ♫

Answer (score 6):

[image]

DON'T MESS WITH ME!
(DENG RAO)

[shadow-fight-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shadow-fight-3)

Comment: hey, what game is this from?

Comment: Shadow fight 3.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I love my avatar so much I have it tatooed on my body.

[image]

Comment: "NoT a ScRrEnShOt!1!" \*upvotes*