# Screenshot of the Week #60: Moments After Disaster

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This Contest has ended.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16262) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16305)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **60<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Memor-X's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16263/8350) picture from [atelier-escha-and-logy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atelier-escha-and-logy) won with 13 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2022-03-14, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2022-03-21, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Moments After Disaster

Submit your photos of moments after disaster has struck!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Comment: I think I have an idea for what I could post for this.

Comment: For those curious, here is [Screenshot of the Week #11 - Moments _before_ Disaster](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15042/screenshot-of-the-week-11-moments-before-disaster)

Comment: This theme just reminds me of the time [GnomeSlice had to deal with TNT griefing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/20851/28182)

Comment: @Wipqozn I guess I'll stop the comment spam now. Can you please accept the winners of [all the SOTW that you posted](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bscreenshot-of-the-week%5D+is%3Aquestion+user%3AWipqozn+hasaccepted%3A0)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It was *me*. *I* was the disaster.
A disaster for the cleaners.

[image]

I was in [control](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/control).

Answer (score 12):

Turns out the Kraken *really* doesn't like overlapping solar panels. [kerbal-space-program](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kerbal-space-program)

[image]

Comment: aww man, you beat me to the Kraken! Good screenshot though!

Comment: Ah yes, KSP is always a good source of interesting constructs (and their failures).

Answer (score 9):

Check your staging! If you don't, this might happen to your kerbals. [kerbal-space-program](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kerbal-space-program)
[image: picture]

Comment: I feel like a lot of... *after disaster things* can easily happen in KSP

Comment: @TimmyJim for sure, the kerbals here are lucky they survived

Answer (score 8):

"Wheatley, what have you done?!" - I never expected him to betray me like that. GLaDOS seems happy to see me though for some reason in [portal-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/portal-2)

[image: Oh no, not this again...]

Comment: "Moments", though? :)

Comment: @Joachim The moment you realize what Weathley has just done - seing GLaDOS being back - a "oh no, please no" moment.

Comment: This scene is why I replay the game every so often, good shot

Comment: My point was that that disaster was a long time ago. This is potentially moments *before* disaster.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Uplink Game Over Screen]

...ah. I suppose that's what I get for trying to cover up a transfer in the [uplink](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uplink) international bank.

Comment: Fun facts: 1. The misspelling of "seized" has not been fixed since 2001.
2. The blackscreen that precedes this is the scariest screen in gaming.
3. I'd been playing this save file for a good 5 hours at this point, and this was my first attempt at a bank hack in a good few years. Clearly I still need more practice.

Answer (score 6):

After my power was stolen, it was misused to create an monster that destroyed the tree of life. [dragon-quest-11](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-quest-11)

[image]

Comment: You probably want the tag [dragon-quest-xi] :)
Also, I love Dragon Quest!

Comment: Me too, I'm waiting for the next one. there are not so much turn-based rpg's in the west.

Answer (score 4):

[minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition)

A while ago, I thought about which block would be best for scaffolding. It should be producible in large amounts, insta-mineable, placed like a normal block, etc., which leaves these options:

- slime/honey: can't jump normally on top
- End rods: awkward to walk on when placed sideways
- flower pots: gaps to fall through

… and finally: TNT. Nothing wrong with that! So I decided to use TNT for scaffolding and temporary blocks from then on. It went really well for many weeks, I even emptied the water from a swamp by moving a dam of TNT through it, but one day I transported a shulker into the Overworld, over an ocean and into my base, duplicated it a few times and then boxed all of them in with some temporary block: TNT. Then, to transport them into a farm, I placed some rails… and… powered them… oh no…

[image]

[bonus image of a smaller, similar incident with powering rails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8HNH.jpg)

Comment: To answer your question: I would suggest using [scaffolding](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Scaffolding) as scaffolding.

Comment: @Kevin That's one of the reasons why I wrote "placeable like a normal block". Scaffolding placement is super weird. And even if I got used to it, I can still sink into it when sneaking, which is a very common activity on scaffolding blocks. And it's affected by gravity after going out a certain distance. And I don't have a large bamboo farm. Despite the name, scaffolding is actually a worse scaffolding block than TNT. Currently I'm back to what I used in my early days on the server BTW: Netherrack. But often I don't need any scaffolding, elytra momentum exploits let me get almost anywhere.

Comment: It is better in a couple ways, though. It's way cheaper, and it almost never explodes

Comment: Re sneaking: The whole point of scaffolding placement being "super weird" is so that you can bridge without sneaking. It is inconvenient if you want to bridge beyond the support limit, though, so it depends on the surrounding landscape. It's good if you have a ton of scaffolding blocks and are not trying to build too high above the ground (or have some sort of temporary platform made of dirt or netherrack), because when you exceed the limit, the extra scaffolding falls and you can use this behavior to build support pillars.