# Screenshot of Week #61

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This Contest has Ended.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16285) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16320)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **61<sup>st</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Joachim's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16292/163757) picture from [control](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/control) won with 14 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2022-03-28, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2022-04-04, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## No Theme

There is no theme this week.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Answer (score 14):

[image: Limsa Lominsa in Final Fantasy XIV]

Limsa Lominsa at night during the Little Ladies Day event in [final-fantasy-xiv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-xiv)

Comment: Does FF put a copyright date on screenshots? Or is this a cutscene or something?

Comment: @TimmyJim it's Final Fantasy putting that copyright in any screenshot taken using it's native system (where you hear a camera sound and the chat log says Screenshot Saved, [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKThY.png)). this image itself was taken by being in First-Person View (R3 on the controller) with the UI turned off (Scroll Lock Key)

Comment: @Memor-X You're telling me a program actually used the scroll lock key? Alert the Queen!

Answer (score 14):

[a-plague-tale-innocence](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-plague-tale-innocence) is a visual treasure trove.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

There was a chicken manning the guard house at this mansion in Navazgane. Thankfully, it looked the other way as I looted the place!
[image: Chicken looking through the iron bars of a guard house.]

[7-days-to-die](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7-days-to-die)

Answer (score 9):

Sword flourish *(idle animation)* from [zelda-majoras-mask](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-majoras-mask)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The socalled Edwin's lantern.  [dragon-quest-xi](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-quest-xi)

[image]

Comment: Is this game called [tag:dragon-quest-xi-s] or just [tag:dragon-quest-xi]?  I see the "s" version seems to be an enhanced version?  I think it should be tagged as "dragon-quest-xi", but we can make a synonym for the "s" version.

Comment: yes it is. In the "normal" version there is no possibility to make pictures in the game.

Answer (score 4):

I very much hope Sachi really means it as a joke... [grisaia-no-kajitsu](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grisaia-no-kajitsu)

[image: Sachi and her jokes]

Comment: That's a very uncomfortable conversation when there's someone on screen who looks about 12-15 years old.

Comment: According to the wiki she is 15. The personality doesn't help to un-escalate as you can see...