# Screenshot of the Week #62 - Bosses and Villains

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This Contest Has Ended.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16305) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16335)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **62<sup>nd</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winners of the previous contest who tied with 14 votes!

[Joachim's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16311/163757) picture from [a-plague-tale-innocence](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-plague-tale-innocence)

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

And [Memor-X's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16307/163757) picture from [final-fantasy-xiv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-xiv)

[image: Last week's winning screenshot two]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2022-04-11, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2022-04-18, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Bosses and Villains

Submit a screenshot of your favorite (or perhaps *least favorite*?) boss or villain.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).

Comment: We still definitely need GLaDOS for this topic.

Comment: Quick, someone play through Portal in [6 minutes](https://www.speedrun.com/portal/run/me3vg83z) to make a screenshot of it!

Comment: @FabianRöling The cake is a lie!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Respecting the classics in [super-mario-3d-allstars](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-mario-3d-allstars)

[image]

Answer (score 10):

> Wake up and smell the ashes..

His ambivalent role makes the G-Man from the [half-life-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/half-life-series) even more captivating.
I hope Valve will let us see much more of him. Or it.

[image]
Screenshot from the first scene of [half-life-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/half-life-2)

Answer (score 9):

Just Aloy firing a machine gun against a FireClaw in [horizon-forbidden-west](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-forbidden-west)

[image: Aloy vs Fireclaw]

Answer (score 9):

"It's right behind me, isn't it?" – "Yes. And to the left and to the right and above and …"

[image]

This is Vanilla [minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition), no resource packs. Can someone guess how I did it?

Comment: Is there some growth potion or something you can throw at monsters?

Comment: Nope! And slimes and magma cubes are the only mobs with a direct "`Size`" value.

Comment: Does it have something to do with the Wither's invulnerability when it is initially summoned?

Comment: Is it perhaps a perspective trick, where the individual pieces are flat pixel art at a distance (including the floor to give the illusion of  a low render distance) ?

Comment: @Reflexive No. @ pppery Yes! But that's not all.

Comment: Did you perhaps crank up your FOV to max?

Comment: Yes, but that's the case in most of my screenshots here, that's not what creates this effect.

Comment: Since the contest has now ended, here's the solution: As pppery suspected, it's related to the wither's initial invulnerability. It has a tag called "`Invul`", which normally starts at 200 and ticks down as the wither grows a little bit, until it becomes properly active with a big explosion. With commands, this value can be set arbitrarily and the higher it is, the longer it takes until it explodes and the smaller it is initially. With some value, it is extremely tiny, with a bigger value is is tiny, but upside down and in the ground and with an even bigger value, it's bigger again and still …

Comment: … upside down. The value can be increased a lot, to produce bigger and bigger upside down withers, but at some point Minecraft's rendering struggles to display it at all. Another trick you can use is to name a mob "Dinerbone" or "Grumm" with a nametag or command, which turns it upside down. Combining both tricks gives you a gigantic wither that is facing the right way up. So this is actually not an optical illusion, the wither really is that big, but its hitbox is inside the ground and it's not doing much.

Answer (score 9):

The Chosen King in an epic struggle against Cerberus, the loyal guard dog of [final-fantasy-15](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-15)'s big bad - over the rooftops of the Crown City

[image]

Answer (score 8):

[kindom-hearts-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kindom-hearts-3) time to get back what is ours.

[image]

Comment: All issues aside with KH3, this was one of the best moments and OST in the series

Comment: yes the return of roxas. Very dramatic. Hand's  off my friend's.

Answer (score 7):

The last real level of [untrusted](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untrusted)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Fighting the Hekatonchires at the end of the Fate of Atlantis DLC in [assassins-creed-odyssey](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-odyssey). I'm not sure what's the worst: his 10-armed charging attacks, the mutated humans it throws at you that explode into lingering clouds of poison, or the multitude of boulders he dislodges from the ceiling and drops on you.

[image: Hekatonchires]

Comment: This is Assassins Creed...? Boy things got weird for this series hmm?

Comment: This DLC are simulations inside simulations. It kinda somewhat makes sense.

Comment: I miss the days when Assassins Creed was so historically accruate, Ubisoft removed the Crossbow from the early dev of AC1 to ensure the timeline matched.

Comment: Odyssey is ... _ok_ in this regard, but there's an awful lot of mythology mixed into stuff (though they explain it away as being the Isu experimenting on humans). This particular DLC is an Isu simulation where you're running through Elysium (Ancient Greek "heaven"), the Underworld, and Atlantis. And this particular boss is the result of a rogue Isu scientist experimenting on humans trying to create the "ultimate weapon" or some nonsense like that.

Comment: I think the excuse is that the further back in time you go (and I think this is one of the earliest, historical timeline-wise), the more the effects of the first civilizations are directly visible, though the humans of the time don't know how to interpret that beyond gods/monsters/magic. And as time passes, those direct links fade and artifacts are destroyed/lost and what you've got left is mythology. It ... mostly makes sense if you squint.

Comment: @Wondercricket I remember the opening cutscene of AC1 showing Altair using the crossbow and then in game you just never got one.

Comment: @TimmyJim How bout that - of course it's been 10+ years since I've played any AC game (shrug)

Comment: This looks like an Hecatoncheir

Comment: I've never played final fantasy but it's quite similar from what I just googled. The Hecatoncheir seems to be more of a humanoid with multiple arms at the general position of the torso where the human arms attach, while the Hekatonchires has them coming out of other locations so it's more like a "ball" of limbs. Similar concept, at least.

Answer (score 5):

Isaac's Mom (is there anything else to say?) from [the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth)

[image: Isaac's mom]

Comment: I'd cry too....