# Screenshot of the Week #63

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16320) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16413)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **63<sup>rd</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Batophobia's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16322/163757) picture from [super-mario-3d-allstars](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-mario-3d-allstars) won with 11 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2022-04-25, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2022-05-02, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## No Theme

There is no theme this week.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The psychedelic world of [psychonauts-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychonauts-2)

[image]

Comment: Wow, that looks awesome.

Answer (score 12):

[image: The Forgotten City]

The surprisingly beautiful forgotten city in [the-forgotten-city](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-forgotten-city).

Just found this in my Steam library, but it's very impressive so far, especially considering it was apparently made by a team of 3 developers.

Comment: This was originally a Skyrim mod, right? That was also very well received. I think the author of the mod and game used to be a lawyer or so, and starting working from complete scratch on the mod (no experience in game development whatsoever), and quit his job because he wanted to focus on it :)

Comment: Wasn't aware of the skyrim mod bit, but that's fascinating!

Answer (score 11):

[elden-ring](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elden-ring)

Elphael, Brace of the Haligtree

[image]

I’m surprised there were no Elden Ring submissions in the last 2 months, this game is gorgeous!

Comment: who's the murder victim at your feet? LOL

Answer (score 10):

Played through [brutal-legend](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brutal-legend) as a palate cleanser after Elden Ring. For a simple Xbox 360 to PC port, it actually has some really cool design!

[image]

Comment: I remember this game being advertised as "any screenshot could be the cover of a metal album".  Surprisingly accurate.

Comment: @Batophobia absolutely! Lots of relatively pretty scenes, sometimes detracted by 2009 textures, but overall it looked very good

Comment: Definitely screams metal.

Answer (score 10):

Visiting The Gauntlet system in early access [everspace-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/everspace-2)

[image: The Gauntlet system in Everspace 2 early access]

Comment: waiting for this one to go on sale before i buy, but i loved the first one. how similar is it?

Comment: @nightsurfer I've not played the first one much at all, but to me it is a great blend between Freelancer (2003) and Descent (1995)

Comment: Both games were staples of my childhood, no doubt I'll enjoy it when I pick it up!

Answer (score 7):

My view from my base on Atrox in [astroneer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astroneer):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

World 4 (Giant Land) cleared with the Tanooki suit in [super-mario-bros-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-mario-bros-3)

[image]

Comment: That brings back memories... was that the same installment in which the angry sun appeared?

Comment: Yes, that is the one! Just played through the whole game again recently (not sure I ever beat the game as a kid). For an original NES game, it has aged surprisingly well.

Answer (score 3):

[final-fantasy-9](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-9)

[image: eidolon alexander calls the last summoner.]

eidolon alexander calls the last summoner.