# Screenshot of the Week #64 - The Great Outdoors

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This Contest has Ended.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16335) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16426)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **64<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Batophobia's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16336/163757) picture from [psychonauts-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychonauts-2) won with 11 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2022-05-09, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2022-05-16, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## The Great Outdoors

Submit a screenshot of an outdoor scene - anything that isn't indoors!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Comment: From the TimmyJimtionary: "**outdoors**, adverb: *anything that isn't indoors*"

Comment: Haha, I imagine most of the screenshots were taken while playing indoors; might be fun to have pictures of us playing an outdoor video game while we are also out of doors.

Comment: @JonathanDavidArndt that seems a good suggestion for next themes LOL

Comment: Went ahead and added it to next themes ... wheeeee ...  https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16425/53249

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Panoramic view of *Devil’s Thirst* from the mountains in [horizon-zero-dawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-zero-dawn)

[image]

<sup>(which is also my screensaver since 2017)</sup>

Answer (score 16):

[image: Xenoblade Chronicles- Eryth Sea]

The Eryth Sea at night in [xenoblade-chronicles](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xenoblade-chronicles)

Comment: Too bad for the UI, but this one is wonderful

Comment: @pinckerman Is this better?

Comment: @Joachim but how did you...

Comment: i am wondering the same

Comment: It's magic! (But mostly photoshop :D)

Answer (score 12):

It's hard to find a game world — or a screenshot, at least — that both represents a huge world and gets that sense of immersive scale right; the feeling that you as a player are actually a small entity in a vast environment. The panoramas in [assassins-creed-origins](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-origins) are often somehow able to.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

[image: Assassin's Creed Odyssey]

---

[assassins-creed-odyssey](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-odyssey)

Answer (score 6):

The landscape spreads out before me in [world-of-warcraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-warcraft)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The tower is my goal in [rime](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rime)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

"Build some campfires, we need more ash" they said - so we did. Lots of campfires where there was a forest once in [wurm-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wurm-online)

[image: Campfires for everyone!]

Answer (score 4):

Ready to explore [elden-ring](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elden-ring)’s huge open world once more, now playing as a heavy load knight [image]