# Screenshot of the Week #65

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This Contest has ended.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16413) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16441)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **65<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Pinckerman's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16414/163757) picture from [horizon-zero-dawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-zero-dawn) won with 18 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2022-05-23, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2022-05-30, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## No Theme.

There is no theme this week - submit any gaming screenshot!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image: Ponspectors & Melia in Xenoblade Chronicles]

*"We measure! Find treasure! Ponspectors 'til we die!"*
— The Ponspectors

[xenoblade-chronicles](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xenoblade-chronicles)

Answer (score 10):

A cold night at the office in [the-stanley-parable-ultra-deluxe](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-stanley-parable-ultra-deluxe)

[image]

Comment: Ah yes.  The preferred chair of any campfire.

Answer (score 4):

World 6 cleared with the fun & amazing Hammer Suit from [super-mario-bros-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-mario-bros-3)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image: ...]

[fallout-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fallout-4)

Comment: in what world is this Fallout 4???????

Comment: Why wouldn't it be Fallout 4? +1! More of these more artistic/abstract screenshots, please! :)

Comment: Is this during a nuclear explosion? :D

Comment: @FabianRöling I'd venture it's just one of those misty mornings.

Answer (score 4):

Traversing the deep ocean and coming across a Tall Neck in[horizon-forbidden-west](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-forbidden-west)

[image: Tall Neck in deep ocean]

Comment: This looks even better than Zero Dawn.

Comment: @LoreFriendly It sure was :)

Answer (score 3):

This game is my latest addiction. It's the most relaxing game I've ever played! [arcadius](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcadius)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image: lamda-and cornell]

Cornell sacrifice himself for lambda's escape from foddra in [tales-of-graces-f](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tales-of-graces-f)