# Screenshot of the Week #66: Epic Fail!

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16426) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16447)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **66<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Memor-X's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16427/8350) picture from [xenoblade-chronicles](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xenoblade-chronicles) won with 10 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2022-6-06, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2022-6-13, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Epic Fail

Show us your face-palming, gut wrenching, embarrassing epic moments of failure! [Suggested by Wondercricket](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15799/8350).

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Comment: Using `/fill` to place and break hundreds of datapack-modded loot chests was surely an epic fail/mistake: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15232/171580 That frame appeared after a freeze of over 12 minutes.

Comment: I do not have a screenshot, so posting as comment. About 10 years ago on Rock Band 2, my brother and I attempted the achievement "Completing the Endless Setlist without pausing or failing" on Expert. The Endless Setlist was every track in the base game back-to-back, which took roughly 6.5 hours to play from start to finish. Halfway through the very last song, the batteries in his wireless guitar died. When this happened, the "please reconnect your controller" message appeared on the screen, which counted as a pause.

Comment: @FabianRöling did the game ever recover? Or did it just hang endlessly?

Comment: Yes, mainly because I blindly typed a command to remove all items.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[image]

Yamcha being Yamcha in [dragon-ball-z-kakarot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-z-kakarot)

Comment: How can anyone beat this? Seriously.

Comment: nobody s. c. n. r

Comment: @nobody do you mean you can beat this or... no one can?

Comment: No one can beat it 

Comment: @pinckerman Clearly, someone has beaten him rather thoroughly.

Answer (score 5):

A peculiar place to take a seat I'd say. [sleeping-dogs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sleeping-dogs)

[image]

Comment: My kind of place to take a nap

Comment: If I was a building with tiny legs like that, I likely wouldn't have even made it that far.

Answer (score 5):

[image: shorttaken] shorttaken in [dragon-quest-xi](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-quest-xi)

Answer (score 3):

[image: Atelier Escha & Logy]

This wasn't a random encounter. I chose to fight this Dragon in [atelier-escha-and-logy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atelier-escha-and-logy)