# Screenshot of the Week #67

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16441) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16456)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **67<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Batophobia's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16442/222022) picture from [dragon-ball-z-kakarot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-z-kakarot) won with 17 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2022-06-20, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2022-06-27, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## No Theme.

There is no theme this week - submit any gaming screenshot!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Comment: The honorary Arqade mod strikes again! Thanks for handling this - honestly  anyone  in the community can do this too! I'm at the beach so I'm not able to really make these bigger posts easily right now!

Comment: @TimmyJim I didn’t know mods could take vacations?? ;)

Comment: @Wondercricket Nah, it's that new At The Beach SE for all things holiday-related :) (Oh yeah, we do still need a mod to change the 'Featured' tag and main site's widget..)

Comment: @TimmyJim good to know that anyone can help. I never did this because of the widget. Enjoy the beach, btw!

Comment: Yea only mods can change the widget, but hey, we'll get to it eventually!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image]

---

[the-elder-scrolls-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-online)

Answer (score 10):

[image]

Riding in style in [pocket-wheels](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pocket-wheels)

Answer (score 9):

Tyrian Gorge, Khrysalis, [wizard101](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wizard101)

[image]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Summon spell odin]

Summon spell odin [final-fantasy-ix](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-ix)

Answer (score 6):

I just started playing the very promising and Subnautica-esque [the-planet-crafter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-planet-crafter): Prologue.

[image]

Comment: Is this the inside of a space station or a desktop computer? :D

Answer (score 5):

Mind your head!
[image: Dwarf crushed by resupply pod that landed on his head.]

A friend forgot he ordered a resupply pod in [deep-rock-galactic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-rock-galactic)