# Screenshot of the Week #68 - Sheer Dominance

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

#### This contest has ended.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16447) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16468)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **68<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Faither's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16450/163757) picture from [the-elder-scrolls-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-online) won with 14 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2022-07-04, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2022-07-11, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Sheer Dominance

Post a screenshot of something where you *dominated*.  Maybe you owned the enemy team with your 67-3 K/D ratio, beat someone's personal best record by an insane amount of time/points, or whatever you feel you were dominant at!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Comment: The person who best Celeste 100% deathless could post their journal here. And anyone who gets "How did we get here" in Minecraft 1.19, because that now also requires the "Darkness" effect, likely from a living, trapped and persistent Warden, in addition to all the other effects and also preferably not dying. Slicedlime once theorised that you might be able to get this advancement even with his "Heartless" (hitless hardcore) datapack, but only if you get all the damaging effects in the same tick. THAT would be absolute dominance.

Comment: Submissions are closed and the votes are currently 6, 6, 6, 5, 4, 4 and 4, so every vote counts now!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My little brother Hugo dominating the rats, the people present, and this image, in [a-plague-tale-innocence](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-plague-tale-innocence).

[image]

Comment: how is this game? I was unsure to buy it.

Comment: @nobody It's really good! It's beautiful, immersive, well-optimized, and engrossing -- that is, if you like semi-linear story-based stealth action games. It was one of the nicest games I've played in years.

Comment: It's indescribably magnificent, @nobody...

Comment: but an action game nothing for me. I will wait for trails from zero.

Answer (score 10):

Celebrate victory over the boss in [swords-of-ditto](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swords-of-ditto)

[image]

Comment: I don't know the game but it looks kind of too tame? for having defeated the boss the game. Or is it just how the style of it is?

Comment: @TobiasF. It's in line with the style of the game.  Beating the boss isn't really the end of the game.

Answer (score 9):

Next level sheer dominance, sheer arrogance.

One of challenge on current league of [path-of-exile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path-of-exile), each this challenge is contain end game bosses and on top of that we must add extra 5 modifier and double that modifier with "Height of hubris". For example 40% more HP, become 80% more HP !

Adding difficulty to the roof, we must complete "The Feared" where you fight 5 end game bosses at once in small Arena with Maven mechanic, she will buff them, create a duplicate of them or debuff you occasionally. Normal feared is already hard enough, now add 5 mod plus Height of Hubris.

[image]

Comment: Sounds too easy !

Comment: No idea what any of those things mean, but it sounds crazy.

Answer (score 8):

My addiction is CSGO - here's a casual Office game where I have 24 kills and 2 deaths:

[image: 24 kills 2 deaths]

Answer (score 7):

Ten kills, no deaths, and almost double the entire enemy team's kill count.
A new personal record for me in [war-thunder](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/war-thunder).
[image: End of match scoreboard for naval battles.]

Answer (score 6):

[image: got him alexander]
overcome fight with eidolon alexander in [final-fantasy-xiii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-xiii)

the youngest get the biggest one.

Comment: Man, Alexander was definitely one of the hardest Eidolons fights in FFXIII, both mechanically and emotionally

Comment: emotional yes, but I found the fight against bahamut and  Brynhildr more difficult.

Answer (score 5):

Kazami Yuuji, the protagonist of the Grisaia games, once again showing absolute dominance in [grisaia-no-kajitsu](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grisaia-no-kajitsu)

[image]

Comment: Did you pull it...?

Comment: @TimmyJim I did not. If that was a bad decision or not I shall leave up to those playing the game, since massive spoilers ^^

Comment: A bit of a hint: This scene happens close to the end of Makinas route.