# Screenshot of the Week #69!

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16456) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16484)*

---

Hello and welcome to the **69<sup>th</sup>** edition of the Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! [Joachim's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16466/8350) picture from [a-plague-tale-innocence](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-plague-tale-innocence) won with 11 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2022-07-18, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2022-07-25, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## No Theme

There's no theme this week, so just send us the best you've got!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Comment: The code of conduct also applies for week #69… ;)

Comment: @FabianRöling That sounds like an inside joke, but I don't get it :(

Comment: @Joachim you know... 69... *wink *wink

Comment: @pinckerman Oh, yeah, I was wondering about that, but didn't think..

Comment: out of contest, because it is not an ingame image but related to a game: https://i.stack.imgur.com/86h4U.png - My avatar's (Roxas keyblades) [tag:kingdom-hearts-series]

Answer (score 13):

A scientist slacking on his job in [rust](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rust).

[image: scientist had a bit too much to drink]

Comment: Poor work ethic, would not hire again. 2/10

Answer (score 12):

It might look crazy, but she is just trying to help! - Scarlett in [find-love-or-die-trying](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/find-love-or-die-trying)

[image: Scarlett in action]

Comment: Based on the game title, this seems fitting for week 69.

Comment: @Stevoisiak I suppose that is true :D

Answer (score 8):

Modern art in zelda-breath-of-the-wild
[image: 1]

Comment: Yes, that is a giant metal spiked death ball. Yes, I have the One-Hit Obliterator. Yes, this shrine is designed to kill you as many times as possible, as quickly as possible, and as infuriatingly as possible, while still seeming possible. *Stop to Start* is one of the hardest shrines in the game, and I can tell you, it's not fun.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Screenshot]

Taking a joy ride on one of my locomotives in [railway-empire](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/railway-empire).

Answer (score 4):

[image]

---

[fallout-76](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fallout-76)

Comment: I literally see nothing except a lamp in front of a rectangle unless I artificially increase the gamma on my screen.

Comment: @FabianRöling I can see most of the picture... if I enlarge it, I can see it quite easily.  If this were to win, it would probably be hard to see in the widget on the main site though.

Comment: I love lamp!!!!

Answer (score 4):

Lots of hands in [call-of-duty-black-ops-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-black-ops-3) zombies.

[image]

Comment: An all-hands meeting during the zombie apocalypse? These managers have no chill