# Screenshot of the Week #83

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest has ended.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16650) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16681)*

---

Good day, and welcome to the 83rd Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest!
[Batophobia's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16651/222022) picture from [xenoblade-chronicles-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xenoblade-chronicles-3) won with 15 upvotes!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2023-01-30, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2023-02-06 we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## No Theme

There is again no theme this week, but the Screenshot of the Week following this one will cover February 14th, so we'll have [*Love Declaration*](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15076/222022) as a theme.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

EXPLOSIONS! [wonderlands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wonderlands)

Comment: Ah, that moment where you realize: He did it. That glorious bastard actually did it.

Comment: Did you blow up a fireworks factory?

Comment: It looks like he wants to give the explosion a hug

Comment: @FabianRöling Nope.  Just your average, everyday Magic Missile

Comment: In BL2: Tiny Tina's Assault on Dragon Keep, Torgue wanted players to [blow up the ocean](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Afrn8jNMW68). @FabianRöling

Answer (score 10):

The prognosis does not look good…

[image: Hagrid and the unicorn]

[lego-harry-potter-years-1-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego-harry-potter-years-1-4)

Answer (score 9):

yggdrasil the second.  [dragon-quest-xii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-quest-xii)

[image: with big ugly sword]

Comment: Is this your own screenshot or is it a promotional image? Only screenshots you've taken are allowed for various reasons, but especially due to copyright reasons.

Comment: Yes, fresh copied from my backup drive for PS4.

Comment: And why is there a watermark in the lower right?

Comment: @pinckerman While [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/NintendoSwitch/comments/dbtx88/game_screenshots_having_copyright_added_to_them/) is specific to Dragon Quest XI S, apparently adding a watermark to screenshots is a thing some games do.

Comment: This is on every picture I made over shared button.  https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16441/screenshot-of-the-week-66-epic-fail/16445#16445 .  Other picture  I take from a videos not.  But if you don't beleave then you can delete my post. I have no time to argue about that.  It's not worth.

Comment: Didn't want to argue, just curiosity

Comment: @pinckerman  sorry I was a little bit harsh.

Comment: It's ok, no worries

Comment: I remember this happening in contest #61: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16305/screenshot-of-week-61#comment48407_16307 Some games just do this!

Comment: @TimmyJim It seems very common in Square Enix games more than anything else

Comment: Yeah, there were two pictures in contest #61 that had the square enix watermark: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16313/53249

Answer (score 8):

With a few mods, building castles (and whatever else you fancy) is extremely fun and rewarding in [conan-exiles](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conan-exiles). Even if the game itself doesn't speak to you, I suggest trying it for this aspect alone.

[image: A screenshot of one of my clan's former castles showing the keep and part of the wall]

Comment: Is that like base building like we see in Fallout 4? If so that sounds very interesting. Thanks.

Comment: I need to get back to this game. Just the regular exploration aspect was fun -- never really paid that much attention to the base building....

Comment: @LoreFriendly It is very similar, yes, including similar bugs and other annoyances, but quite a few mods to improve the experience, as well :)

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Raptors are the chihuahuas of the dinosaur world in [jurassic-world-evolution](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jurassic-world-evolution).

A deinonychus challenging a tyrannosaurus rex. (spoiler alert: the t-rex won.)

Answer (score 5):

[image]

BOOM! [fract-osc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fract-osc)