# Screenshot of the Week #84 - Love Declaration/Valentines

Tags: discussion, community-event, screenshot-of-the-week

## This contest is over.

*[previous contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16658) | [next contest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16693)*

---

Hello and welcome to the 84th Screenshot of the Week!

To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest!
[Batophobia's](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16659/163757) picture from [wonderlands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wonderlands) won with 13 upvotes (and Batophobia is now on a 3 post winning streak)!

[image: Last week's winning screenshot one]

---

To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

- One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
- Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
- To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
- Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.

#### How long will the contest run?

We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2023-02-13, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.

After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2023-02-20 we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

---

## Love Declaration/Valentines

As described [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15076/163757):

> Either between characters or from a character to an inanimate object/concept, either funny or sad, there's a lot of ways one could declare their love.

I'll also say that anything *Valentines* related works!

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a [question of its own](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/screenshot-of-the-week-themes).  Additionally, there is the [hall of fame](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14939/screenshot-of-the-week-hall-of-fame) you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Comment: `I'll also say that anything Valentines related works!` ... am eagerly awaiting plenty of Fallout 4 screenshots featuring [everyone's favorite synth detective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nick_Valentine) ... ;)

Comment: I would upvote that! I even know a place where I could link to this to get a lot of people to upvote that.

Comment: aw HECK i was just playing through The Outer Worlds, and there was a cute date scene on the ship! Too late to go back :(

Comment: It appears 'love' (and its declaration) is not our community's strong suit 

Comment: @Joachim I knew it be a tougher theme. Not many games do events for valentines. Events for holidays usually help for this kind of theme

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I'm still waiting for someone to post that character. I bet if I post in r/aromantic, which has 85560 members, it could easily top the 6 upvotes that the current top submission has. It's basically an auto-win, does anyone want it?

Comment: I almost missed this one... glad I paid the site a visit today!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oz74 unit (called millium) hugs jusis albarea in [trails-of-cold-steel-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trails-of-cold-steel-3)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

No words needed - the image speaks for itself in [find-love-or-die-trying](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/find-love-or-die-trying)

[image: No words needed]

Answer (score 5):

*Will you be my Valen...*

[image]

*...tine...?*

---

Paris, the "city of love" in [assassins-creed-unity](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-unity)

Answer (score 5):

I went through some of my screenshots and found this (admittedly) blurry shot from [bioshock-infinite](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bioshock-infinite). I think the game had the blurry filter over all of the background for this segment!

[image]